# Would help a "canonical question resource" avoid crappy questions get answered?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Lately I've been reading about low quality questions and how the high reputations users get tired of watching all the time the same bad questions ([Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions)), and more important, of watching how bad questions are all the time answered.

As much of the crappy questions usually are answered before, my question is, **why don't discourage people from answering "low quality questions"**?

By **"low quality question"** I mean questions that **have already answered more than twice**, and keep being asked in the system. In MySQL and PHP I've seen asked a lot of times really easy questions that get answered in seconds and gives you a lot of reputations. Lets say you're a low reputation user,
that are the kind of questions you'll like to answer because it'll give you reputation easily. This promotes the site will have questions of low quality answered, because the "fake internet points" are addictive. But **what if instead of giving you reputation for answering low quality question, it'll give you reputation for linking to "canonical answers"?**

I'll explain myself: I read this answer about how to create canonical answers, ["Duplicate questions" versus "RTFM"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251946/duplicate-questions-versus-rtfm/252046#252046)
and see it repeated in [What can be done about repetitive questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-can-be-done-about-repetitive-questions), and I had the idea of make some "punishment" and "gifts" to avoid the bad behaviours to users who only answer questions to get reputations, even
if they know the question is answered (I've seen copy/paste the answer from another question instead of flag it as duplicated). For that, the system will need to have "canonical questions", and have some modifications:

- The "canonical questions" will be those wich has been marked and accepted as a resource from a duplicated one.
- Every time a question is marked as duplicated AND ACCEPTED AS DUPLICATED (I have no idea of the best way of accomplish this, maybe when it reaches some community votes AND a moderator markes as DUPLICATED), the OP loses all the reputation he earned with that question (as he did not paid enough attention before posting). Of course, all answerers 
  will lose the reputation earned (upvoting and accepted answer), as they didn't flagged the question as duplicated.
- Every time a question is linked to a canonical source, and marked as duplicated, people who flagged it win reputation (10, 15 points, I don't know how much, but they did a really important things: Avoiding noise in SO)

This way we will have in the system really well answered questions, and as people get their points out when they don't make an effort to improve the place, they will pay attention to 
mark questions as duplicated.

And as a collateral effect, the main queue could be quickly filtered out of all the duplicated questions (as linking to valid resources will give you repo and answering low quality questions will be a waste of time when the question will be marked as duplicated), helping all the the users (not only high reputation users) to find questions it deserves the pity answer.

Do you think this would help improve the system?

Comment: Duplicate: [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) .  Now give me my 10 Imaginary Internet Points.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the answer because is in another SE site, :P. But that is the idea

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with your use of 'low quality' to denote questions that have been answered more than twice.

The quality of a question has *nothing to do* with whether or not it's been asked before. Quality refers to the content of the question itself, not its relationship with other questions.

However, your main argument, that questions that have been asked and answered before [is an old feature request that hasn't yet been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions).

Comment: Not performing a basic level of research for a question *does* make it a low quality question.  If the question's answer was already easily discoverable then that question *is* of low quality.

Comment: If the information was already readily accessible, yes.  If the information was not readily accessible, even if it existed somewhere, then it can be a question that's actually adding value.  Going around duplicating content that someone else might want to find down the road is never helping anyone solve a problem that they couldn't have solved without that question.  It is adding no value.

Comment: If the post is using radically different terminology than the information generally *isn't* readily accessible to the post author, because they didn't know how to find it, that is unless searching on the terminology that *they used* would find the answer. Having 5 duplicate posts in the google search results is not superior than 1 result that has a good answer. I take "low quality" to mean a question that does not follow the guidelines for how to ask a question that the site gives; guidelines that includes "do your homework". That's actually the *first* point in "How do I ask a good question?"

Comment: By "low quality post" I mean posts that are so general and so easy to find an answer doing a minimal google search (usually you find the answer in the first 3 results) that the only thing it does is adding noise (so, low quality, it doesn't add anything good to SO). And as @Servy points out, it doesn't follow the rules of SO of what to do before posting as "Do a little of searching before posting", "Do your homework", and so on