# Can my old question get a "collaborative effort" lock?

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki, locked-posts

When I was relatively new to the site I've asked: [Best practices of building a website using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11311672/1348195)

It is still very useful to visitors and on topic, but it has grown very broad and right now provides a lot of irrelevant information since no new answers can be posted. It is closed as "too broad".

Given the new "collaborative effort" lock trend, would it be a good candidate for such a lock? If so, what would be the best way to ask for it?

Comment: What would a *"collaborative effort" lock* entail exactly?

Comment: @NiekHaarman a diamond moderator (or someone with higher permissions) to mark it as such. This means that the question and answer are locked and are both marked "community wiki" so anyone with sufficient permissions here can edit them. This means I (and the person who provided the answer) will not get any additional reputation from this question - rather it will become "collaborative effort" where everyone is welcome to contribute. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api (single community wiki answer with many edits)

Comment: `what would be the best way to ask for it?` I think you found the best way

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I thought only the question gets locked, not the answer.

Comment: Poor, unacceptable question, even if you were new to the site. I would close and downvote it. But hey, because of the lock it can't be down- and close-voted anymore. Please delete it by yourself.

Comment: Here comes the hate train... That question actually still attracted lots of upvotes and I got messaged "thanks" because of it in the last month, but I guess I can't please every self-righteous user. As for your "kind request" I'm afraid your rudeness and disrespect will not gain you much other than the sympathy of other rude or disrespectful users, I hope you find comfort in that.

Comment: I don’t think much good can come of that answer. As it is, it’s just one person’s opinion. It’s not clear how you want people to collaborate on it. Should it become a big list of modules? Is that really helpful?

Comment: @minitech I plan to edit it extensively - not with modules but with the mindset change that comes with the migration and how to deal with it. I'm planning to edit it into a conceptual answer of how to deal with the migration issues rather than an outdated practical one.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please do never accuse me as a *hater* again. Memorize this. I address serious problems with your question. Multiple of the close reasons apply, and I see questions like this close and down-voted (multiple times) in a minute every day. What makes the worth out of your question (except from being highly ranked in search engines)? I'm really asking, maybe I missed something.

Comment: @hek2mgl That sounds like a much better tone thanks. What it addresses is how to first approach developing a website (or webapp) in a Node environment coming from a language like PHP. There are several big conceptual issues I now understand I did not back then and I think can help - the switch from mainly stateless requests in PHP to a stateful "central" server in Node. The layout and structure of flow control you have to weave yourself in node (vs mostly the ability to do so in languages like PHP), the focus on middleware in the ecosystem vs standalone modules etc. Mostly conceptual issues.

Comment: Hopefully, once I'm done editing it (it'll be a while) you'll see an answer that is less opinion based and more focused on the conceptual side. The current answer given the question, and the question itself are borderline and I honestly believe they can be salvaged into something relevant. Undoubtedly, if I (or someone else) am unable to do so such a Q&A have no place here as opinion based and tool recommendation - although that will not be the case once I'm done with it. There is no personal gain for me by keeping it here (rep is already fixated), I just want to create a good resource here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I like event oriented programming too, while knowing that there are disadvantages as well. In minimal projects I would address the overhead, in complex projects I would address that it *could* lead to code which is harder to follow (I told *could*). However, the thing that could be addressed as a problem with your question is that you are asking for a *good* way without providing an actual use case. Mostly this is seen as "too broad" or "does not provide code ... " ... However, there are forums where this could be dicussed, but as by it's current definition not on SO

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Am I so wrong?

Comment: @hek2mgl In fact, you are quite right and the current answer "spreads thin". Which is precisely why I asked for this lock and do not intend to speak of programming with events in the revised answer (since it is basically just JavaScript concurrency) or anything involved with that but rather specifically on building a website with NodeJS and the concerns involved like - Managing resources in light of state (you don't need nearly as much in PHP or ASP.NET), keeping the server running, middleware approaches (like express), how to deal with failure (which now affects the whole server) and so on.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Btw, I just dropped my first comment because I really see questions like that every day being closed and didn't understood why other rules should apply for a highly-ranked-in-search-engines post. I still think this is ok to say. But however, I think the key to an answer to your question (here, on meta) is the term *collaborative effort* ... I feel like I don't got this... Could you explain? (I need to be AFK for a while.. Can be tomorrow, but will come back to this post)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Seeing that the *hate train* comment earned 13 upvotes, (which I can't really understand), I think that our discussion here was at least not leading to an answer to your question and we might delete comments therefore if you confirm.

Answer (score 3):

Robert Harvey locked it, so it's locked.

For future visitors, there are reasons to wiki-lock an answer. You can find an up to date reference [in this Meta Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280530/16587).