# Who deleted my comment on this question and why?

Tags: support, comments

I posted a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965186/why-does-language-verbosity-have-a-negative-connotation) thinking Programmers.SE would be a better fit for it. Apparently I was wrong, and two other commenters explained why.

But my comment was also deleted, and now the other two folks' comments are out of context.

1. Who deleted my comment?
2. Why?
3. Why wasn't I notified?

Comment: A better question is why the responses weren't removed as well.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Probably because '09 was a different time for Stack Overflow.  That question was fine back then, but it isn't now.

Comment: @Makoto: I was referring to the *comment* responses. They are from two days ago.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Fair point.  They probably should've been removed, too...

Comment: @NicolBolas - I can't speak for the moderator who reviewed these, but comment flags are presented without context. If we remove a comment, it can sometimes be hard to see all of the following comments that refer to that one. Additionally, in cases like this where someone makes a possibly incorrect migration suggestion, there can be value in leaving behind the commentary explaining why something shouldn't be migrated. This may prevent future suggestions of the kind.

Comment: Don't suggest people post their awful questions on other sites.  That's kinda rude.

Comment: What Brad and Nicolas said. Either leave my comment and the replies, or delete the entire exchange. But deleting just my comment leaves the others without context.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are temporal; they may disappear at a moment's notice without any notification to anyone.  That's just their nature.

With that said...the question was asked almost **six** years ago, so any [migrations would be impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/175248).

Having had a closer look at this question...even if it *were* eligible to be migrated, I think it'd get rejected in a heartbeat, and rightfully so.  Here's what it's asking:

> I hear people comment on Java's verbosity (and other languages) as if it were a bad thing, why? To me it makes code easier to understand. Less typing seems like a really trivial argument.

We have:

- Opinionated question (verbosity of language)
- Personal opinion on said question
- Dismissive attitude towards another possible position (trigger phrase: "trivial argument")

...which would make it off-topic anywhere.  Migration isn't meant to help migrate crap; even if the question would be *more* on topic elsewhere, if it's in a poor state, it should be edited into shape or deleted.

Comment: I am sad to see the question deleted. My only problem was with the comments on it being out of context. Can you please take a look at [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year/286970) and consider undeleting the question, but keeping it closed?

Comment: @DanDascalescu:  No, I'm not keen on considering undeletion for that question.