# Why was this 7 ½-years-old question deleted 18 months ago, even though it has tons of upvotes and views?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, popularity, vote-to-undelete

I was looking at MySQL clients for Windows when I got to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows) by a link found somewhere else. Luckily I have +10k, so I was able to read it and it was kind of helpful.

The question has 235 upvotes with 86 stars and many highly voted answers.

Should it be undeleted?

Comment: Probably because it was off-topic then.  Now, it's even more off-topic and should not be undeleted.

Comment: Regarding the (probably newer) policy we don't answer questions to find 3rd party resources, the question was closed and deleted righteous. We don't want opinion based answers like these, but straight forward answerable questions like a FAQ.

Comment: As I've said before, [just because a question is off topic does not mean it should be deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/16587).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, that answer is the reason i created this question

Comment: Off topic yes but it was asked 7 years ago, received positive response, gained a lot of attention, and most importantly is useful. Glad to see it was undeleted. Context is always key, something people tend to oversight.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Sure. Though "just because it is up-voted and much-viewed, does not mean it isn't poison" must also be kept in mind.

Comment: As I've said before, it has a lot of votes because a quarter of a million programmers looked at it.  That's because Google used to like SO and would rank *anything* high that matches keywords.  Only one in a hundred programmers that looked at it found it worthy of an upvote, not exactly a ringing endorsement for quality or usefulness, is it?  Leaving this trash lying around is why Google doesn't like us anymore, querying "best windows mysql client application" now list the kind of sites where this stuff belongs.

Comment: I really have no authority on this site's rules. But I can tell you one *TRUTH*: "deleting something straight which has been revised/edited by developer community in hope that it will some day help someone else, putting hours in those edits over years and years is *SIN* ". There should be stackoverflow-off-topic-questions-site on stackexchage. If stackoverflow really dont want to keep these questions which community contributed over years, it has got no eternal rights to lock them. Just move them to this off-topic-sister-site and let them breath alive. No offense.

Answer (score 45):

No it should not be undeleted. It is off topic. The question being asked is:

> Is there any application that you can recommend to me? Free would be a plus, but anything up to $100 would be okay, too.

On top of asking for a recommendation, the question itself contains 5 "answers" by listing 5 different products.

This question is off topic *and* doesn't split it's own answers out of the question itself. It should remain deleted.

Comment: You may want to pitch in here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315458/can-we-re-delete-what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows

Comment: It has had too much of an impact to be deleted. There are always exceptions, and this is clearly one.

Comment: @EpicByte: If you had written that comment all that many months ago, it might have been viable. Maybe, though probably not.

Comment: Plain and simple, questions like this bring eyeballs to the site and that brings ad impressions. They are not going to allow a question like that to be deleted now.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Jeff and Joel realized, when they first created the site, that such shortsighted views tended to harm the community, and, while they would help in the short term, clearly tended to be harmful in the long term.  That mindset that valuing quality will pay off monetarily in the long term has worked quite well for them.  Now, it has been fading away with time, but I'd like to think that those core values aren't entirely dead yet.

Comment: @Servy - the quality mindset is only a priority for those that joined the site early on and earned their rep from answering questions with answers that were so comprehensive that additional answers were always subsets of the quality answer. Rep meant something, rep has be diluted with inflation because you can ask basic stupid question and get hundreds of upvotes and never answer anything. Rep based on answers should be worth more than rep based on quantity. Removing **quality** from the charter drives this new mentality of **quantity first** in new members.

Answer (score 39):

No, it should not be un-deleted. Although "closed as not constructive" is no longer a valid close reason, if that question were open today, it would be closed as an off-topic software recommendation.

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Most of the content is actually from *2008*, and 7+ year old software recommendations are rarely any good. This question also shows little community effort to maintain quality over the years.

In some cases, although old or off-topic content can deserve a wiki or community lock when well-maintained or historically significant, this question does not look like a very good candidate.

This question might be on-topic for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but we don't have a way of migrating this question over there, plus it was closed about 4 years ago so it's likely very dated.

If you think there's content worth salvaging, you might consider adding it to a question over there, or creating a self-answered question if no such question exists.