# Can we re-delete "What is the best MySQL Client Application for Windows?"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete, historical-lock

Link for 10k users for context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows

---

**This question has been deleted again by a moderator.** It would be nice to read what argument was given that motivated the deletion.

---

I know there's another question asking for the undeletion, and since despite the [outcries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315429/792066) [of keeping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315430/792066) [it deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315428/found-a-1-%C2%BD-years-old-deleted-question-with-tons-of-votes-why-it-was-deleted#comment298669_315434) were ignored, I think a call trying to move the community against this movement is necessary.

---

Following the format of [Should we delete "What's the best C++ JSON parser?"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829/792066) I will **try to** assess objectively the actual value of this question, pointing out merits and faults of this post.

### Title

Is evident for most of our very seasoned users that the title is very important. Is the presentation card of the question. What the visitor should expect to find when they follow a link and it has been repeated in several occasions that a *good title* should summarize what the body is about. Well, this question has a catchy title, we agree, but it fails to describe what the question is about. It gives the expectations to the visitor that they will be given a run down of (dis)advantages of several options. The preliminary lookout seems detached from this expectation.

## Body

This question seems pretty specific of what the user is looking for. I ask for applause for the OP.

- It gives a reference framework of what he's looking for "what the Enterprise Manager / Server Management Studio is for Microsoft SQL"
- Details what specific features he's looking for: "Editing table structure should not be a PITA", "adding a new row in a "column-list table" as it is done in the Management Studio.", "visualize "foreign key relations" between tables".

I feel that this OP read [Tim Post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/208/226) before he even wrote it, just a few tweaks in the wording, less verbosity and this question could fly on SoftRecs. Sadly, these details weren't reflected on the title, which reads "what's the best X", which as I said before sets the expectations of what kind of answers you will read/write for the question.

## Answers

The real king here. Answers. Most of the time, we are said that great answers may convert a bad question into a good one... well, remember what I said about the title? Basically, most of the software detailed here are answering the title, which we agree is neither specific nor objective, and forgets about the constrains the OP sets on his question. Lets analyze them one by one:

- HeidiSQL: it makes reference to one of the four "nice haves" (adding columns/rows, database diagrams, price, and being loosely equivalents to Enterprise Manager/ Server Management Studio) and even then **fails the single constrain**. Then it references another minus point which through I believe is important to know, it wasn't even asked in first place.
- Toad for MySQL: Through it doesn't have one of the disadvantages of HeidiSQL, which was never part of the constrains, it fails to address the only one referenced, and doesn't address the other 3 requirements.
- MySQL Workbench: this one, doesn't even address any requirements given, and the only references are "cons". Not sure why was this one useful?
- SQLyog: finally! One that addressed all hard (?) requirements, it tells you outright price, that "Editing table: works nicely." yet doesn't offer details, and that doesn't offer diagrams. Score 2 out 4.
- DbVisualizer: it glances over the tables "display" like a spreadsheet, but only as minus, and even adds the term "Confusing"...
- Navicat: only tells us that it works on Windows and for less than 95 if you are an individual. 1 (?) out 4.
- Nucleon Database Master: when I read this for the first time, it gave me the impression that this was copied from the product description at the company page, too marketing-y. I only found a [2012 blog post](http://joachimdamico.typepad.com/blog/2012/07/lyrics-sql-database-downloadable.html) which contained the first two paragraphs, yet it **failed to address any of the requirements**.
- List of stuff: only names, zero descriptions.

So, out of 7 proposed "solutions", only one addressed most requirements yet neither fulfilled the two most important: key visualization and adding rows/columns in a spreadsheet-y. As a recommendation question, I have high expectations that what I will find will fulfill my needs at reasonable levels, yet these solutions fails to do so.

## Cool metrics

People says that when we delete a question we somehow "break the internet". It uses links, views, votes, and other metrics to decide so. Well, first of all, **votes are not equal to *quality***. If it were, we wouldn't have so many failsafe mechanisms on the review system to prevent audits from selecting posts that are known for having experienced one or more events that tend to skew these metrics, for the sanity of everyone else. Or, given delete votes so users can delete what roomba decides needs human eyes to decide.

Now, outside Stack Overflow, Google says [there are 603 references](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9185%2F%22+-site%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/%22+-site:stackoverflow.com&tbs=li:1) to this question. I don't know neither Russian, Japanese or Chinese so I can't vouch for those, but the English sites are basically mirrors/scrappers/translators (the last one is new for me) of Stack Overflow. [One of the blog](http://ilmuinternetkurniandoko.blogspot.com/) which has a link to this question, I'm not even sure what is doing the link where I see it. [This 2013 blog](http://stanley-huang.blogspot.com/2013/05/level-1-popular-mysql-gui-client-tools.html) only use the content to make its own list of clients. Doesn't reproduce the content of the answer and apparently it wasn't important anyways. I feel that the internet didn't even felt when this question was deleted a bit more than 2 years ago, and it should have stay like that.

Can this be re-deleted, so it doesn't pulls downward the median quality of the site, and makes more users frustrated because their expectations of the high quality curated content wasn't fulfilled?

Comment: Fwiw most of these were cons because most of the "answers" were imported from the question body, where it was primarily commentary from the author explaining why he didn't think each of those solutions solved his problem, which is also why they don't really make sense as answers. They weren't really meant to be answers - they were meant to be more "anything else other than these which I don't want to use?"

Comment: It's 35 to 40 pseudo answers or comments morphed into a community wiki that is a work-in-progress. I see no harm in its existence if, for no other reason, alerts people of options. Again, it is editable.

Comment: @Drew then it has been a WIP for 4 years, I see no interest of anyone to "finish" this... nor to maintain it after it's finished. Is dead weight.

Comment: A few lines for each, not pages. An on-network page to point people in need. I don't see the issue. *Edit:* I just think there are bigger fish to fry, and a precedent elsewhere that suggests it stays. I am not invested in it either way.

Comment: We should not make it a precedent to delete questions that have had massive positive impacts like this one. There are always exceptions and if this isn't one then I don't know what is. It would cause more harm deleting this question then keeping it, simple as that.

Comment: @Drew it doesn't fulfill a *need*. People are given the impression that this will be a curated list of the *best* MySQL clients, we are far cry there.

Comment: @EpicByte did  you read the framework question that I used as template to write this one. Metrics of  "impact" is as useful as a arbitrary metric. Current usefulness is and will always be the baseline.

Comment: Whether or not anyone agrees with you, let's be clear: 12 votes is not an "outcry", it's barely a "meh".

Comment: @EpicByte *"massive positive impacts"* On what are you basing this assertion?

Comment: @Ben well, I blame that "meh" to the poor visibility of the question, since it was never *hot* enough to appear on the Community Bulletin, giving it the view/votes boost.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Its large amounts of views, up votes, community contribution, just to name what comes to mind.

Comment: @EpicByte can you be more specific? Specifically in that "community contribution" that you refers to.

Comment: @EpicByte As several of us have said, views are not an indication of quality. Votes maybe, but how do you evaluate votes from 7+ years ago? I really don't see the community contributions to the question as being exemplary though, although I'm not 100% sure what you mean by this point.

Comment: I guess I'm in the minority here. I'm just worried of establishing a precedent of deleting questions that have had this kind of impact. I'm really not a fan of deleting content unless it truly benefits the community.

Comment: @EpicByte I'm more worried about establishing a precedent of undeleting every *crap question* asked on the Dark Times of Stack Overflow.

Comment: If anyone has any constructive ideas on how to deal with a historical question  that has "good link juice" as George Stocker mentioned, please suggest a solution. No one is suggesting we like the question, the quality of its answer, or believe it should have been here a week after it was first written.

Comment: @Drew Is "good link juice" something that needs a solution?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm wondering what kind of fruit is needed for that?

Comment: @Drew what "good link juice" is and how is that relevant for anything?

Comment: What are the implications of breaking links. I don't know. George made it apparent that a migration on network was a problem. Were it to migrate to the Recommendations site, that would be great. But that was discussed, no?

Comment: @Drew well, if he says that breaking links is a problem, I think I demonstrated that the internet as whole isn't even linking that question in a useful way, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Missing the conversation about why it can't be migrated perhaps?

Comment: @Drew migration was never on the table if you read animuson's comments. You can't migrate a +60 days old question. Which is kinda why nobody will ever say anything constructive about migrating.

Comment: That is my point. What is your solution to links? How can you solve the problem that handcuffed George into undeleting it?

Comment: @Drew **blow them all up!** Why would anyone care that scrappers have broken links?

Comment: If you say so. Until then I will wait for the constructive part.

Comment: @Drew I'm still missing on what topic you want to construct over. Broken links are not an issue, and George is, in my opinion, using that fallacy as argument. No one will give you the constructive discussion you want, because no one consider that something that we should bother with. Now, if you feel that broken links are something you care, **make your point**, so people can discuss with you that. Don't expect that people will figure out what  you want if you don't tell them.

Comment: I am sure George can come back and answer here too.

Comment: I hope i didn't find and open the pandora box, I hope this will also trigger a healthy debate at higher level too.

Comment: I think what we really need is the way to respectfully and painlessly retire such questions (and no, the way how [meta-tag:historical-lock] is implemented now is neither respectful nor painless). Whatever google juice they get, it should not be associated with Stack Overflow, so that their visitors wouldn't imagine that stuff like that belongs here

Comment: Links, links everywhere, but none of them to sauce.

Comment: I must state that I find it incredible that a moderator has devoted so much effort to this. A significant effort at consolidating answers, at least two long meta-answers, and all the thought processes required. Why? Isn't there something else to do?

Comment: @Braiam Oh come-on that is a very loaded statement, and judging by the up-votes it has received it looks like it worked. Highly voted off-topic questions do not translate to undelete all crap questions and you know that.

Comment: @EpicByte but, we are programmers! We love consistency, and when we see one *consistent behavior* we expect everything else to behave the same way. Through you and I know it wasn't your intention, it gives that impression.

Comment: @EJP formally, 200K+ views justify [Atwood's cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773). Informally, moderator likely wanted to demonstrate readers how they [stand by their claim](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315428/why-was-this-7-%c2%bd-years-old-question-deleted-18-months-ago-even-though-it-has-to?lq=1#comment298587_315428) that question shouldn't be deleted - and answers that were there before cleanup made such claim totally ridiculous

Comment: Could the best elements, if there are any, of questions like these (old, popular, now off-topic) be included in the "Documentation" that is coming along? Then there's somewhere for anything  that is useful, and the questions/answers themselves can be deep-sixed?

Comment: @BillWoodger you can do it. Nobody's stopping you.

Answer (score 65):

[To quote George himself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/70345),

> We do not delete good content.

This question is not good content. Its "answer" is even worse. I'm not going to go into what's bad about it, because @Braiam has done an excellent breakdown of that already.

High upvotes and favourites are not an indication of quality, number of views is not an indication of quality, number of links from Google is not an indication of quality. **There is no justifiable reason to keep this question around.**

This question is junk and it should be deleted, *unrecoverably*, as soon as possible.

**Addendum:** To address the point that Jarrod Roberson brought up in his comment below, *I don't give a flying f__k about "good content" that generates many impressions* (and neither should you). If Stack Overflow has descended to the level that we have to keep rubbish around to clickbait users in to find something that is so low-quality it doesn't help them one iota, **then Stack Overflow has failed**.

Comment: *Good Content* is that which brings crap tons of eyeballs to the site and pays the bills with ad impressions. You are conflating *good* with *quality*, the later was removed from the charter for the site over a year ago. This is how it is now. It is very clear that this question is considered what they want the site to be now regardless of how much *community* wants it gone.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson "Stack Overflow is run by the community." Moderators are only a small part of that community. If the community says a question is bad, and a moderator says it's not, then it doesn't matter what the moderator says; the community has decided, and the moderator has to respect that decision. Otherwise SO has failed, because it's no different than any other forum where the admins and mods decide what goes and the community gets the scraps.

Comment: I would say it is a bad idea to delete any high traffic question. The reason is that it is clearly one end users want to ask as such if you delete it the question will just reappear as new content on the site now to be answered by some new user who doesn't know. This completes the cycle of bad content which is something that would be good to avoid. Instead they should be locked and closed and any future versions closed as duplicates of that one imo.

Comment: @Sammaye there are two kind of traffic: good traffic and bad, toxic traffic. This question only attracts the later.

Comment: That toxic traffic will always be there, without these questions to close to the toxic traffic turns to toxic content as well

Comment: @Sammaye Having a canonical, closed question as a dupe target for similar questions is not a bad idea, but at the end of the day *nobody should be asking this type of question anyway because it's off-topic*. If we leave this question open, someone has to close the duplicated questions as such; if we close it, somebody has to close the duplicates as off-topic. Either way, somebody has to action them.

Comment: @IanKemp though gold badge holders can action without oversight now, don't forget that

Comment: @Sammaye on what tag, if I may ask?

Comment: @Braiam in this case mysql?

Comment: As I see it we have two choices. The first is to make the content bearable as it will be, at best, that. The second choice is for it or a replacement to have a home on some other site where it truly belongs. Landing on a dead page seems not to be an ingredient of a good business model.

Comment: @Drew, remember that this *was* deleted - with a dead link to nearly everyone - for over 18 months. It was only in the last 24 hours that the link was available for users that have less than 10K reputation.

Comment: Then I say deep six it again. The world seems to have survived those last 18 months.

Answer (score -6):

Why not move this to [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? With a title change (*MySQL Client application like Enterprise Manager / Server Management Studio for MS SQL?*) it seems fit for that site (as the OP states, the *answers* are not that good, but the question looks OK).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/213575

Comment: @Braiam You mean to say "It is too old"?

Comment: Arg, it didn't have the "Don't migrate crap" rule... well, that works too.

Comment: I think it has been said a few times on SO that we shouldn't migrate crap to other sites, so even though it can be asked there, there seems to be a consensus that it shouldn't be moved

Comment: SR.SE has specific topicality requirements (see [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/352)), and - although I'm not intimately familiar with the site - I suspect questions of the "what's the best foo" variety don't satisfy those requirements.

Comment: @Yannis. I know, that why I said 'title rewrite'. The question is fine over there.

Comment: I don't see how rewriting the title would be enough of a change to fit SR.SE's requirements. There simply aren't enough constraints in your rewritten title (and I assume question body) to help it avoid the kind of answers the current version got. How does one objectively pick the better answer in that question?

Comment: I second the idea to move it to SR.SE, I'm sufficiently active there to know that it can be brought into shape. Saying: Yes it is not a great question, but I've polished worse ones.

Comment: Good to know that the question could find a home at SR.SE @AngeloFuchs, however migrating it wasn't really a possibility (questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated).