# Why is tag burnination (and everything it entails) important for you?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

So, tag burnination was once again questioned. The thing is that those questioning it never ever reach any constructive discussion including the participation of the large base of users. So, let's give the opportunity to the advocates of curating the content by tag removals a soap box to speak of. Why is proper tagging important to you?

BTW, "tags burninations are important because puns" can't be used... I already did ;).

On the third hand... I'm not mentioning bounties... :/

Comment: A [link to the proposed process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work/250934#250934) would not be remiss here perhaps.

Comment: How can you tag this [discussion] when you exclude everybody for whom burnination is *not* important?  Only asking for responses from people that think like you is, well, there's a circle word for that but I can't say it here :)

Comment: I closed this question, not necessarily because it is "opinion-based" (opinions are fine on Meta), but because it seems to be a biased attempt to solicit answers from people who have the same opinion as you. If someone wants to advocate for the importance of burnination, they can do it on [the question that calls burnination into question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318426/could-we-stop-with-all-those-burnination-requests). We don't need one question for each side of the debate.

Comment: @CodyGray so, because I asked a question that attacked neither side, as neutral as it can be, I'm taking sides? I love that logic.

Comment: *"So, lets give the opportunity to the advocates of curating the content by tag removals a soap box to speak of."*

Comment: @HansPassant because I know when a discussion will be totally unproductive, I took the path where by not taking sides allows everyone to speak up, in a constructive way

Comment: @CodyGray and? The other side have had plenty opportunities, and have been heard before, so I'm inviting the ones that haven't been heard without attacking the position of the others. How is that not neutral?

Comment: There are two different arguments here, you cannot make both. You first claimed that this question was neutral and unbiased. It is clearly not, as evidenced by a quotation from your question. Now, you seem to be admitting that is true, and arguing that the other side *needed* a chance to speak. Sure, fine, but why can't they post an answer to the question that prompted this one? My claim is that we do not need a separate question for each side of the discussion.

Comment: @CodyGray no, I'm admitting that if I took any stance I wouldn't have a constructive discussion, so I took the positive approach. And this is not the first time that a antithesis question have been asked http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315458/792066, specifically so the discussion gets more coverage. The other discussion was buried, without allowing everyone that can participate and have an opinion to participate.

Comment: "it never ever reach any constructive discussion despite the participation of the large base of users"  This is true for the whole of meta. Or rather, things are discussed endlessly, over and over again, but never result in site changes. Now imagine how great it would be if SO devs were tasked to implement the meta consensus, instead of spending all their time making things like unicorn animations, funny hats or "Teams".

Answer (score 30):

A question can only have 5 tags, sometimes these are taken up by "noise" tags that should have been banished.

When choosing the tags for a question, I see a list of matching tags as I type, I only want to see tags of value in that list.   Seeing "noise" tags make it harder for me to find the correct tag to use.

Sometimes we have xx-ggg and xx-yyy tags to cover very different concepts if the "xx" tag is not banished, it will get used in error.

(Most questions are asked by people with little experience of the site, so we need to use **all** the tools we have to help them tag well.)

Comment: Upvoted for great answer, but I guess this begs the question "Why do we only allow 5 tags per question?".

Comment: As opposed to what? 10? 20? Unlimited? How will any question ever have an exhaustive list of tags, then? There's a lot more to a question than its tags...

Comment: Risking sounding like 640k is enough for anyone, 5 tags would seem plenty enough for most questions. Sometimes it feels like beginners to the site would be better off with a lower limit. For example, it feels like most PHP only questions also tag MySQL just to fill out the tags.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: One of the lesser tags that I'm extremely active in often gets added as filler. I've made probably at least a thousand edits that are *just* removing that tag alone for that reason. Sometimes I feel like even 5 is too many for a good portion of questions out there.

Answer (score 10):

Burnination is important to me because I hate fluff. The best way to prevent fluff is not to offer stuff that can be abused as fluff by new users.

People don't read. Then want an answer within the next two minutes so they tag the hell out of the proposed tags they can in the hope to get as large an audience as possible, so hopefully someone will answer their (of course urgent) cry for help.

We can't help that, what we can do is limit the number of cries we put out. So putting it through he mergeinator, burninator, https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFaNf.jpg will remove the fluff options.

When it doesn't exist you can't choose it as a low rep user, so you can't pollute it. You are forced to be concise and on topic. That way if you are in need of checking a certain tag, you don't have to choose between 3 different varieties of the same tag, and you just can browse the single topic.

Also, excersising the (mob)rules is fun https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxCoE.jpg

Answer (score 10):

Some of the tags we burninate are because they give the indication that such questions are on-topic when they are not.

- legal, copyright (we don't answer legal questions here)
- code-quality, code-smell (we don't do code review requests here)
- software-tools (we don't do tool recommendations here)

Answer (score 2):

Even if I don't participate much on tag burnination, I think it is important to keep the site useful. The easier is to reach good and relevant content better.

When I search in a tag, I want relevant answers related to tags

Comment: How does tag burnination do this? Your answer seems to be completely unrelated to tag burnination. You *can't* search in burninated tags, because they do not exist after they are burninated.

Comment: But the remaining tags do exists and are more relevant.

Comment: @CodyGray Existing bad tags tend to crowd out good tags, be it in auto-complete or actual tagging of posts, even if the maximum of 5 tags per post is not reached.