# Deleting "irrelevant" tag from high scoring question

Tags: discussion, tags

Lately I have been really active in answering question in [reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportlab). At some point I checked the list of high scoring question and it turns out that the [top question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721818/django-get-the-static-files-url-in-view) isn't really about [reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportlab).

The question mentions using [reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportlab) but beside that everything about this question including the answers is about [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django). As the question in this case comes down to:

> I managed to build the URL but how would I get the local path to the image?

As this is not related to [reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportlab) I feel the tag is irrelevant.

**So my question is:** In this case would it be okay to delete the [reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportlab) tag from this question in order clean the highest voted list of a small tag like [reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportlab)?

Comment: I don't know what the score have to do with tags...

Comment: I found it relevant as a high score indicates it is an extremely useful question, so removing a tag from such a question seems like a large step. As such I felt it would make sense to ask the community whether it would be acceptable to do so.

Comment: Removing tags is not a "step"... it wasn't removed immediately after it was asked, but later. More important than "score" (which is more about how popular a question is, kind of a "like" button) is using the tags that objectively categorize the question.

Comment: Got it, but beside the score argument, it is okay to remove irrelevant questions, right? As it helps to keep the "categories" objective and clean.

Comment: Of course, removing tags is a often thankless but important task. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318481/why-is-tag-burnination-and-everything-it-entails-important-for-you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reject an edit from the Review Queue, **irrelevant tags** is one of the available reasons:

> Tags should help describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

Your case seems to be a textbook example of this case, so you could certainly edit it out. If you see anything else about this post that can be improved, you must improve that as well. But, be aware that an edit which removes only a tag is often rejected as being too minor.

In the end, the *motive* behind the edit doesn't really matter. As long as the edit improves the post, it is good.

Comment: In this case it only makes sense to remove the tag as the question is fine beside the tags. It seems weird that such a edit have a big chance of being rejected, but I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: It passed the review, 3 vs 1. The rejection was not even about the edit being to minor but about it deviating from the original intent of the post which I find slightly strange. But no need to worry about that :)

Comment: @B8vrede well done. Sometimes, you're unlucky and hit a couple of bad reviewers.