# Question deleted after being closed for no apparent reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

*Please read this older [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/1709587) by a SO moderator about another question, a widely visited community wiki*.

This post is [regarding this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991705/json-vs-pickle-when-passing-data-between-processes) ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wDu.png))

This question was recently deleted (edit: currently it is locked due to the dispute) after being locked. I consider that questions should only be deleted (by someone that is not the owner) if they are completely inappropriate for the site, and they are useless.

In my opinion, this question should only be closed, not deleted. Downvoting and closing are already two very effective mechanisms that serve as a triage for good or bad questions. I understand that to delete a question the thing has to be blatant.

Even though in this case it is arguable whether the question is off-topic or not (on the one side, 'pros and cons' questions generally tend to be bad quality, but on the other hand, it is referring to a very specific issue of programming), there are several reasons why I consider that it should not be deleted:

1. The content of some of the answers is valuable and concise. It is useful for other people having the same question (which is a typical, specific dilemma in programming).
2. Users answering have invested time and effort providing a summarised, concise recollection of reasons supporting the features of each architectural option, raising interesting points that have research and reproducible examples.
3. Other users have engaged and helped with their comments polish the content of the answers.
4. Bad answers can be deleted or down-voted, and the question can be locked and put a notice mentioning the position of SO on whether it is recommendable to follow this post as an example for asking.

In summary, **even if closing it prevents bad content from appearing, deleting it disables people from accessing good content** (I am not boasting about my answer being great, I am generalizing). I think that deleting knowledge is never good. I believe that this step has to be taken after weighing whether it would do significantly more good than harm.

(Disclosure: besides from the reputation loss, which I confess I do not fancy, this is not the point I am trying to make).

I would like to receive an explanation on why despite all my points the question should be deleted. **Honestly I don't understand how it can be good deleting it**, I am certainly unhappy with it but I am not trying to complain. I don't expect a "because SO rules say so", but rather a "why SO rules say so".

**Edit**: the flag for the question being closed is:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The premise is the answers will be opinionated rather than based on facts and references, but in this case it does not hold to a considerable part of the content.

I consider appropriate enough this notice that is put when questions are locked:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

You can have several examples; one might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). As a user mentioned in the comments, if the answers are good, I would not consider the post as a whole to be noise.

Comment: It's admittedly a terrible, overly broad question, one asking for opinion, and looks to have been appropriately closed. I wasn't involved in closing it, but I surely would have avoided answering it.

Comment: Yeah, and I agree with it being closed, but I don't see the point in deleting it. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Off topic questions *should* be deleted, and so I do very much see the point as it helps improve the signal-to-noise ratio of the site.

Comment: Do you not think that the information that it contained was instructive? Even when one tries to delete their own post for being down voted, if it has quite some answers that have effort, SO does not allow you to delete the question for the harm it could cause. However, that restriction does not apply to moderators. I don't see the reason for the double criteria @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: If you put it like that, I think a lot of questions should be deleted that are closed with the flag of 'historical importance' or similar tags (very bad questions that were popular and serve as reference for the quality of the answers)

Comment: @StephenLeppik: Impossible. Questions with accepted and up-voted answers cannot be Roomba'd. If you look at the deleted question, also you'll see the names of the specific SO site members who did the deletion.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde: I don't argue that your answer was good, but someone could write a terribly helpful and informative answer about automobile repair, but since it is off-topic, no matter how good it is, it is at risk of being closed/deleted.

Comment: Well, there ya go -- meta has decided (or a mod?), and the question has been un-deleted. I may not agree 100% with the outcome, but I don't have to -- Democracy works

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels According to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51991705/timeline), no mod was involved, just 3 users.

Comment: Also, just a point of note: "there are many other SO posts that happen to be in the same circumstance" Examples of off-topic questions that are not handled appropriately is not a valid excuse for new off-topic questions to not be handled appropriately; there are millions of questions and only around one or two hundred users who actively moderate the site... the reason an off-topic question is not closed or a delete-worthy question is not deleted is always: "because it hasn't been seen yet by [enough] moderating users".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is right. Off topic questions should be closed and deleted. The fact that you are losing reputation is an unhappy byproduct of the fact that you, and the other users, shouldn't have answered that question at all, much less received bounty for answering it.

Comment: this is going to be a del/undel vote war... 2 delvotes again so far.

Comment: I a question has good and valuable answers the question is NOT NOISE.

Comment: That question arguably isn't even opinion based anymore.  It's asking for pros/cons.  It has a ton or research and detail put into the answers, and provides value.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic at its core.  Asking about the pros and cons of two commonly used serialization technologies is exactly the kind of question you need to go to SMEs for. How should a question like this be posed so as not to be off-topic or opinion based?

Comment: Well guys, if you agree with me and think the question is valuable, vote for opening it again. They have just deleted after undeleting it. I firmly think that there is no good in removing knowledge.

Comment: "pros and cons" are not an objective quality. It is still a POB question.

Comment: @yivi The answers provide objectively useful information.  Hence my vote to undelete.

Comment: Whether you consider that "pros and cons" questions are good or not, that is not the debate. The point is whether it is appropriate to delete an arguably bad question that has good and useful answers where people have invested effort and research, based on the fact that either "it is noise" (which it is not) or "it leads to other bad questions" (which can be solved by closing it and locking it). Is it fair?

Comment: I was replying to your call to "opening it again". I don't mind it being undeleted (nor I care if stays deleted). I think it would be wrong to reopen it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I used the wrong word. I meant undeleting :)

Comment: The question has just been locked.

Comment: "This question exists because it has historical significance," Well, this particular question has no historical significance, it was not asked a long, long time ago when some rules were different. It is just a month old and managed to flew below the radar - it was not closed in time, before it attracted answers.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I did not say it was historically significant. My point was to say that it could be locked without being deleted, and that a notice could display that it is not recommendable to ask such questions (as the sentence follows), but however it exists because of the relevance of the answers that it contains.

Comment: In regards to your latest edit: It is an old answer about a (now very) outdated pile of garbage of an answer... It's not a very convincing stance to suggest that shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is not the question he is commenting on but his position on the topic that I consider relevant in the conversation. I do agree that that particular answer was not very good since it is just an enumeration of options. The case for this question is different: it is a comparison about _only_ two specific tools, in a very common programming issue (data serialisation). Its scope is much narrower and the answer (in my opinion) could be more relevant.

Comment: And that question is still off-topic...

Comment: @Cerbrus while I beg to differ, that is not the point I am trying to raise here. I think I have made myself clear in the body of the question in Meta, and subsequent comments here. I believe that repeating you think it's off-topic constantly does not answer my question.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Actually, no, it's not really clear what you are asking. There is, quite literally, no question statement at all in your post. The question was deleted because it was off-topic and downvoted. You seem to have some misunderstanding about question deletion, such as "As far as I know, questions can only be deleted (by someone that is not the owner) if they are completely inappropriate for the site". No need to be completely inappropriate, slightly inappropriate is enough to warrant deletion.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I edited the post to make clearer my points and the question I am asking (though it is trivial that this is 'why should the question be deleted')

Comment: That question had a bounty, that makes voting in a high volume tag less than a reliable indicator of value.  But if this is a choice between leaving a crappy question around and losing yet another contributor then the choice ought to be obvious.  We don't have a lack of crappy questions.

Comment: i mean... i'd rather lose the contributor if it means less crappy questions staying around. There's more joining every day.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde That's contradictory. To that trivial question "why should the question be deleted", the answer is trivially "because it's off topic and people voted for it to be deleted".

Comment: Only driven by curiousity, I checked your profile and saw an answer to [this very interesting question/debate space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256003/4396006). You're basically saying you'd rather delete my answer and loose me as a contributor than having the chance (as small as it may be) that someone will post a bad question after seeing that. Well, I must say that precisely due to SO being huge, I'd rather prioritise the action of answering (good contributors that are willing to make an effort) to asking.

Comment: If you prioritise asking, this is, having new users that drive traffic to the site and produce revenue, then yes, you will grow in questions (and in income) which you can later filter and obtain a higher volume of quality, but you will loose fundamentally good answers. Those new users are unexperienced and ironically tend to produce worse questions. However if we care to produce a positive atmosphere (not necessarily friendly though), more users will be willing to answer better and enrich the community.

Comment: Banning a question that was formulated incorrectly but received good and useful feedback is the very exact representation of the practice of disregarding contributions while trying to solely filter the signal-to-noise ratio of good questions. No matter the points I raise, the answer is always 'question off-topic, delete'. I thought the site was supposed to be useful. On-topic rules are guidelines that generally tend to be positive, not the Bible. One has to judge if it is actually good to slam answerers in the face and say 'hey, know what, I don't care about you, we have a thousand more'.

Comment: You could have posted your answer to an on topic question instead of an off topic one. that's the risk you take when you choose the off topic one.

Comment: ah gdi. there it goes, the welcoming hidden card. gg everyone.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier if that is the only thing you are going to say about my comment, then yeah. Ok. I don't mean it to be happy rainbows, I am OK with being somewhat mean in certain contexts if that is positive to the site. I am taking about the general attitude that he is pointing about prioritising new users to dedicated contributors. To be fair, none should be prioritised.

Comment: I do not wish to prioritize new users. I wish to prioritize good on topic content. Leaving an off topic post open is counter productive to that goal, regardless of whether or not it results in the loss of a long-term contributor.

Comment: @KevinB I did not mean open (I agreed with closing it and locking it), I meant deleting. And I don't think you can disregard the answerer. By deleting the question you may be cleaning up off-topic question, _but_ you are also deleting a good answer. That is the balance I believe we are talking about.

Comment: Couldn't be biased since  you have answered with currently 7 upvotes ? ;-).

Comment: I see "no apparent reason" in the title, I think, "There's a very good reason and this person just doesn't know how to recognize the quality problems in their question."

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde The phrasing made it sound as though George Stocker's answer was related to this situation. It's three years old, about a somewhat highly upvoted community wiki question and highly (+350) upvoted answer. This has no ground with the current situation. I edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier yeah, I agree. It is related but it is not the same circumstance. Fair enough.

Comment: It's been a while but based on the image, I feel even if the question isn't useful or relevant to SO, it is still useful to me. The answers there are also very good and top quality and they are definitely something I would have come across when I would have Googled for a solution.
(Of course I do understand the reasons for the deletion and am not debating it, but I did like the answers and the quality of discussion the question generated)

Answer (score 25):

The guidance on the [delete questions privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) is rather brief:

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

In my opinion, the question does have *some* value, and is not blatantly inappropriate/off-topic enough to  be deleted solely based on the fact that it's not an appropriate question (it can provide insight to people looking into interprocess communication in Python, since one answer provides a brief overview)

Especially considering the answers, that should be considered when deleting a question, the question should have remained closed (to indicate it's not an appropriate question), but not deleted, so people may view the question and answers on it.

Comment: "the question does have some value" how about extracting that value into a good question?

Comment: Well, it was removed again. I think it should be undeleted and locked. This is ridiculous.

Comment: I tend to agree - the question isn't the greatest, but answers do have significant value, especially the security issues mentioned.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde You've already raised it on meta. The next step would be flagging it for moderator attention and requesting an undeletion and a lock, but since it's not a very clear-cut, I don't know how that'll end for you (edit: also already undeleted again)

Comment: Occasionally I see questions that are [closed and immediately deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522694/how-to-find-out-which-row-contains-array-of-numbers) because they aren't easily comprehensible, so their askers aren't given a chance to clarify or paraphrase them.

Answer (score 11):

There are two distinct (but related) concerns here:

1. Should this question and all its answers be deleted?
2. Should this question even be closed?

For simplicity, I'm going to try to address these in reverse order...

#### Gorilla vs. Shark: when do "versus" questions need to be closed?

The identified problem with this question is that it demands opinions over facts, not because of any unfortunate wording choices but because of the fundamental needs its author seeks to address: choosing one option over another. This is an age-old dilemma:

- Coffee vs. Tea
- Nails vs. screws
- [Dogs vs. Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear-baiting)
- Sunny-side-up vs. over-easy
- Alien vs. Predator
- Bacon vs. sausage
- [Old shoe vs. glass bottle](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)
- Emacs vs. Vi
- [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Ah... But those aren't all quite the same sorts of questions. While folks might pit bears against dogs (or aliens against predators, or gorillas against sharks) for their own twisted amusement, there are lots of scenarios where one might have the necessity of choosing between, say, fasteners or editors or even beverages.

**The keyword here is *necessity*.**

Most folks *don't* actually need someone else to choose their editor for them. Unless you're building an OS distribution and only have room for a single editor, in which case you probably *do* want to do more than just wing it.

Most folks are free to drink whatever they wish to. Unless they have a problematic allergy, in which case this question suddenly becomes a lot more necessary and a lot less subjective.

If you're building a bird house, screws and nails are more a matter of personal choice than anything; if you're building a house that has to comply with local building codes and come in under budget, you better not wing it.

This was the crux of [Jeff's blog post on the matter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/):

> And most critically, give us context. Explain why you’re looking at this, and what you mean by “better” *[...]*

If there's no *need* - if this isn't [based on actual problems that you face](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - then you're just trying to stage a fight for your amusement. And if there *is* a need, then **that need takes center stage**.

Jeff lays out a whole four-point test for identifying problems with these questions, but I think we can make this a whole lot simpler:

**If you can rewrite the question to take the form *"What X should I use to accomplish Y in scenario Z?"* then it's not too opinion-based.**

...And also, you should probably rewrite the question.

Now, let's see if we can apply that to *this* question:

- **What's the scenario?**

  > These two processes are launched by multiprocessing.Process. That data is usually of the sort of dictionaries, lists, and so (just like the data that JSON would allow).

  *[...]*

  > Processes are able to send each other strings or bytes.
- **What needs to be accomplished?**

  > I have two processes in Python that need to communicate data.
- **What's the problem to be solved?**

  > I have though about either using JSON strings and loading and dumping the data in each side, or doing the same with pickle.

Ok, that's a *little* awkward, but it's pretty clear we could rewrite this question:

> What serialization method should I use to pass data between two Python processes?

Ok, so the underlying needs of the author are fine; they could've asked this in a less controversial way and been fine (which is good, since lots of other people have *already* asked essentially this question).

Does that mean we should just rewrite the question? Hell no! At this point, that'd invalidate most of the answers, and we'd probably just end up with a duplicate anyway. But this does give us some useful questions to ask the asker:

- What sort of data will you need to pass?
- How much of it will you be working with?

The asker may not know the answers to these questions. But asking them - and trying to answer them in the question (or admitting that they're unknown) gives us more context, a better understanding of the core **need** here. Anyone can *guess* that JSON is going to be less flexible and less efficient; identifying where that is likely to become a problem makes for a useful answer and by extension a useful question.

### When should a closed question be deleted?

I'm gonna make this one simple: a closed question should be deleted **when there's no chance that it should ever be reopened.**

Some folks always get real sad when I say that, but... They really shouldn't. A closed question is like a rock sitting on top of a steep hill: it might roll one way, it might roll another, but it probably won't stay put forever; if you *really* don't want it to roll North, then you'd better push it South.

[image: Artist's rendition of a question pending deletion: large rock about to roll down hill onto someone trying to reopen it.]

By the same token... If you *really* don't want a closed question to be deleted, then you'd better reopen it. A question becomes eligible for deletion pretty fast after being closed; don't suppose that you have years to sit around and think about it.

### In closing

The big issue here wasn't that the question got deleted. It's that it got closed. And that in the month *before* it got closed and the month *after* it got closed, no one tried to ask those questions and build up a more concrete context, no one tried to dispute the reason for closing, and **no one voted to reopen**. That big rock just sat there, waiting for someone to give it a little nudge...

Comment: Yes, that's why I always say: fix the freaking question. I don't get why people get so hung up in these issues when the solution is easy. Make the question better, or make better questions.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go a step further than just advocating undeletion and say that I think - unlike most of the commenters on this Meta question - that there is nothing profoundly wrong with this question and it deserves reopening.

Having to make a choice between two standard serialisation formats for some data is a situation programmers regularly face - a ["practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center's lingo - and in *this particular case* the pros and cons are objective, few in number, and straightforward enough that they can be completely enumerated and explained in a few paragraphs. Asking for such an enumeration of pros and cons is neither "too broad", nor  "primarily opinion-based".

The final paragraph, which currently asks *"If anyone has any alternative that is better, I would also like to know about it."*, does admittedly broaden the question considerably and take us into tool recommendation territory. The proper remedy to that, though, is surely to just delete that paragraph entirely and thereby narrow the question's scope to only that implied by the title. We don't need to resort to closure just to deal with a secondary question in the final paragraph.

I'm going to make precisely that paragraph-removing edit, and then vote to reopen.

Comment: Questions comparing two products without well-defined criteria don't fit Stack Overflow very well. This is a [Gorilla vs Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) question, guidance on those has generally been to close them. I'm not that familiar with multithreading in Python, but my general experience with such questions is that they essentially only can be answered with a thorough explanation about how both products work, highlighting the differences, and such content is usually too broad, or with an opinion, and those are of little value.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I don't think the details of how multiprocessing works are relevant to the question; the existing answers don't explore them, and I don't see anyone suggesting that they're incomplete. As for the characterization of this as a *Gorilla vs Shark* question, I disagree, for the reason in this answer: the pros and cons here are few and objective. There are already answers posted to the question that describe them all. Jeff's canonical *Gorilla vs Shark* example asked to compare two entire programming languages; that's hugely different in scope to comparing two serialisation formats.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Or to put it another way: the question that you're labelling as *Gorilla vs Shark* does not exhibit any of the 4 bad traits that Jeff says are characteristic of *Gorilla vs Shark* questions in the *What, specifically, is wrong with asking Gorilla vs. Shark?* part of his blog post. This question has immediate practical relevance to a specific problem the OP has, it's specified narrowly, it could easily become a useful resource for people facing the same choice to learn from, and as a consequence of those things there's nothing about it that should "drive away experts".

Comment: Meh, afaik multithreading and multiprocessing are broad enough subjects to have this problem. The answers aren't that objective, things like _faster in this undefined test_ are strange and might not be applicable (the OP is way better off testing himself, which the answers sort-of say), and the security arguments are unsubstantiated (limiting the available types != security) and it's also unclear if this applies to the OPs problem, it's all very vague imo. Imo argument 2, it's not nearly specific enough, is applicable, this question is too broad.

Answer (score -3):

The question was not following the rules of Stack Overflow (at first). You can see my comment about it (first comment on the post). It blatently violated this rule of the help center:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

**Those are all problems you don't want. Opinions and spam *should* be avoided.** But if you take a look at the answers, most of them are not opinionated (ironically the user with nearly 40k rep left the only opinionated answer), and none of them are spam. My answer is  a list of facts (and a recommendation), and so is the selected answer.

Furthermore, the question was changed to be more pointed and ask about the pros/cons of each. It's since been edited again to ask something different, but that's sort of contrary to the point.

**It turns out that we ask questions like JSON vs pickle all the time in real life. These are reasonable questions (in reality), but you just have phrase them the right way in order to avoid opinions on this particular forum.** Opinion based questions can still share knowledge and be extremely useful, and can *usually* be re-interpreted to meet the rules of the forum. (i.e. which is better JSON or pickle vs. List some pros and cons about JSON and Pickle).

**Anyway, I wouldn't get hell-bent on reading the rules verbatim. Everything in English can be interpreted in different ways. We're all here to learn and contribute, and if a question is borderline rule-bending (but *useful*), I say we let it slide.**

P.S. I only came here b/c I noticed wild rep changes. It took me a while to find this particular post on meta. There was a link telling me that the question was locked and to visit meta for more info, but it might be nice to actually just link to the meta question so I don't have to hunt for it:

```
locked by Jon Clements♦ 4 hours ago
This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.
```

Comment: "i.e. which is better JSON or pickle vs. List some pros and cons about JSON and Pickle" the only difference between each is that the former is opinion based and the later is too broad.

Comment: @Braiam *How* is it too broad? It's not like the question is about comparing applications or programming languages, it's just about comparing two data serialization formats. The pros and cons can be comprehensively explained in a  few paragraphs.

Comment: @MarkAmery compare all properties of a gorilla and shark.

Comment: @Braiam That's not a valid analogy, since I specifically said *some* pros and cons not *all* pros and cons. Furthermore, do you answer questions you're asked with *absolute* completeness? If I ask how to print to console in C, do you answer with *all* that happens? Are you going to walk through tokenization, lexing, parsing, build a syntax tree, optimizations, and assembly generation, and then explain how that assembly actually displays the content in my console (EE lecture incoming about signals and systems, too)? There's *always* an interpretation that a question can be "overly broad".

Comment: @MattMessersmith which pro and cons should you list? "Some" is ambiguous and open to interpretation in which every potential answerer will have its own set of differences varying importance. That wouldn't happen if you *narrow* the difference to an specific context or situation.

Comment: @Braiam You're right, but *all* questions are like that. There's always some interpretation you have to apply. For example, how to print a string to console in C is a perfectly valid question. But which string do you print to console? There's an *infinite* number of strings you *could* show how to print. It doesn't matter which string you pick, because no matter which string you pick, you've answered the question. Same thing goes for pros/cons to list. List as many/few as you want: in any order desired. It's up to the answerer to use discretion in this regard (and it always has been).

Comment: No, @Matt. Only too broad questions asking for the differences between objects without establishing the context and goal against what they are evaluated are like that.