# Closed and deletion of "Creating a web server in pure C"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

How is the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/409087/1122645 deleted? The OP is clearly specific about the details of socket programming.

There is even an answer with a sample server in few hundred lines.

Comment: The answer being a few hundred lines long is a good indicator that the question is too broad. It was closed as such and later on it was deleted.

Comment: The non-informative answer to your question is "because a few people voted to close it, and several people voted to delete it." You'll probably get a more useful answer if you ask specifically why it's too broad, and provide your justification as to why it's not too broad. That way, if you provide a good argument, it can get undeleted and reopened, or another person can point out why it really is too broad and show why your interpretation is incorrect, then you learn from it. Either way, adding a more specific argument to your question will be advantageous to getting a good answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: no, those are about different questions.

Comment: That question required 11 votes to delete.  There's no way I or anyone else is going to resurrect it.

Comment: Since I was one of the people who cast a delete vote, I'd like an opportunity to justify what I did before this gets hammered (somehow, someway) as a dupe...

Comment: @user000001 _Duplicates_ are rarely chosen because of exacly same questions, but for answers which answer the OPs problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: So should the [specific-question] tag be burninated?

Comment: @user000001 Particularly, both [Erik's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375053/7795130) and [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375184/7795130) greatly apply to this question. Erik's for explaining why the existence of an answer doesn't imply the question is on topic, and Shog's for why such questions should be deleted. Their answers answer this specific question.

Comment: @user000001 _"So should the [specific-question] tag be burninated? "_ No, but as long that answers would apply for that specific mentioned question the meta question can still be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I cannot be voted to be undeleted anyway. Since Yvette voted to delete it, her mod vote is binding and only a mod can undelete it.

Answer (score 15):

This deletion and my vote on its deletion happened a while ago, but in looking at the question I would delete it again.

The synopsis of the question is simply too broad - "How do I write a webserver in C" is pretty much the whole of the question.

This is not unlike the infamous ["How do I write a forum"](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) question we associate with so-called "help vampires".

In essence, the question - in spite of it being asked during an era when Stack Overflow was still trying to establish what was and wasn't a good question - is pretty poor.

- There's no objective "right" answer, as stated by the OP's lack of requirements.
- There's no starting point or struggle to *help* with; we would have to [*teach* the OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368558/1079354) how to do this.
- There's *less* value in this kind of question these days than there would be in  perusing [the source code of Nginx](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/master/src) or [even Apache](https://github.com/apache/httpd).  To add salt into the wound, Apache's been around since the 90s and I'd be very, very shocked if the source code wasn't somehow available in some way in '09.

Comment: Browsing the source code of Nginx or Apache does essentially nothing to help you write a basic, simple web server in C...