# Please stop deleting our content without coherent reasons (regex tag)

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, specific-user, regex

After becoming aware through other users that questions might get deleted just because they do not fit into the mood of some (few) others I dug into my own answers and noticed a considerable number of deleted answers. The problem is specific to the regex tag.

Most of these questions are average questions, [neither off topic nor of extremely low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Below are some examples. You will need at least 10k reputation to view deleted content.

- [Regex for letter and number combination for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764588/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWAEk.png))
- [Regular expression for accept only 1 occurrence of "space" and "single quote"...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319085/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtoIA.png))
- [Why this regex with backreferences work in regex101 but not in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415372/)  ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1IjV.png))
- [How to remove   whenever it occurs between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338996/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC0Fu.png))
- [Notepad++ Regex on xml file - Create new element automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74282311/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrbKY.png))
- [Match a certain word if it is not enclosed in double quotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210752/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GJCW.png))
- [Write a regex to match title case sentence but ignores numbers and special chars...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913442/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eudqY.png))
- [JS RegExp Get Words That Contain String And Dont Have Certain Characters...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563020/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABeH2.png))
- [Remove HTML tags and their content from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72594776/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1lms.png))

Please stop deleting content of other contributors for any personal reasons.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to how some of those questions were voted to be deleted; [Regex for letter and number combination for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764588/regex-for-letter-and-number-combination-for-password) has a *positive* score, and questions can't be voted to be when that is true.

Comment: @Larnu a question can be deleted if it's closed. For [10k del-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you need to wait 3 days. For [20k del-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you can vote as soon as the question has score of -3. But in both cases a closed question can be delvoted after enough time has passed. The one you linked to was deleted *while closed* then reopened after deletion.

Comment: Then I must admit, deleting content that is deemed helpful/useful does seem like incorrect behaviour.

Comment: The regex tag suffers from `icanhazcodez`.  These kinds of questions are routinely deleted in other tags.  The custom nature of regexes precludes making a library of regexes from Stack Overflow posts; every one of them has unique requirements.  The number of upvotes doesn't matter if the post is not on-topic.

Comment: That's just the usual friction between what Stack Overflow is and how it works versus how Regex questions work. (Almost) all those questions are just "gimme the regex" questions, because existing regexes don't match their specific requirements, which isn't quite surprising. There won't be any peace until either Stack Overflow changes its rules or when Regex moves to their own sub-site.

Comment: [What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405460/8967612)

Comment: There's actually another alarming pattern that I only started noticing recently. That is, removing the [regex] tag from questions that are very clearly about regex especially when they get answered by other users. That's all I'm going to say.

Comment: The same user again...

Comment: @Tom "*(Almost) all those questions are just "gimme the regex" questions, because existing regexes don't match their specific requirements*" Doesn't this describe... literally all debugging questions?

Comment: Folks are suggesting about [regex] being a tag where every question is unique, but this seems to contradict the first example listed: it had a suitable duplicate, but you reopened it. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: It does appear that you have a heavy stake in some of these questions, by answering them even though there were suitable duplicates. I do not condone swift delete-votes on questions where such is unwarranted, but if we are to put the moderation of the tag under scrutiny, I think we should not turn a blind eye to other bad patterns.

Comment: This would seem more like an actual loss if the Q&A were actually useful beyond the literal question – i.e. applicable as duplicate targets. Surely *someone* must have asked for using regex to verify letter+number passwords?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi isn't that the chronic problem on this site in general? If a bad question already has a good answer, then that's worth something.

Comment: @TylerH In a way it does and to be honest, I don't know why those questions are accepted here.

Comment: @shadowtalker I'm more pessimistic on that. If there are good answers but even their authors see no worth in them for any good questions, is that really worth something?

Comment: @Tom Well programming questions are literally the point of the site so I'm not sure how it's not clear...

Comment: @TylerH You know very well that not all questions are allowed when they don't match the goal of building a repository of questions actually _usable_ to future readers. Regex questions and debugging questions are very specific and hardly usable to anyone else. I wasn't around when the "too localized" close reason was removed, but I'm sure there were compelling arguments why too localized questions are perfectly suitable to future visitors and not just more sand.

Comment: @Tom A question doesn't _have_ to be useful to future readers, it just has to be on-topic. If someone has a question about or problem with code that is objectively answerable, it is allowed, even if _you_ may find it not useful or boring. Your comment that the "too localized" reason _being removed_ just underscores my point.

Comment: Something about this whole trend smells a bit funny. If this hasn't been nuked by the time I get to an office, I could offer a perspective in the form of an answer.

Comment: More regexp questions need to be deleted, not less. ideally automatically via roomba, but people vote weirdly in regexp.

Comment: I don't typically say this, but a large amount of those linked questions, have been deleted since this meta question was even asked. It's not entirely clear the reason some of the higher quality questions (code provided, current input provided, and a clear indication of the desired output) all without any grammatical or spelling mistakes contained in the post were even deleted. My description only applies to a handful of those examples. *One of the questions was restored, but the link description, wasn't updated.*

Comment: [Why are duplicates being deleted?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrbKY.png).  The question wasn't well received, which is fine because it was a pretty awful question, but why was it closed then deleted? I suppose the real question is, why was it answered in the first place, instead of flagged as a duplicate?

Comment: @SecurityHound eh, only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74282311/notepad-regex-on-xml-file-create-new-element-automatically) of the linked questions was deleted _recently_, and that was _before_ this question was submitted...

Comment: @Cerbrus - I had to open all the links with their screenshots to get a better grasp of which questions were actually deleted.  You are correct, most of these questions, were deleted awhile ago.

Comment: @TylerH *"even if you may find it not useful or boring"* Only "boring"? Pretty weak attempt of a strawman argument. But since you don't seem to understand what I wrote here, I can make it a bit more clear: I stated why I think regex questions will always cause friction in the moderation and I agreed with you that debugging question fall in the same category. I don't campaign for any rule changes, I don't vote to close any of those question, so what I may find "useful or boring" is completely irrelevant in this matter.

Comment: I also agree closure is generally wrong in cases like this, but these aren't high quality questions deserving of sticking around forever. The system has a process for cleaning up "too localized" questions, unfortunately the animus against closure/curation has lead to a default stance of upvoting everything in sight in tags like regexp, rendering these systems useless in that area.

Comment: @Tom The examples of 'not useful or boring' are not exhaustive, just exemplary. Those minutiae do not make my response a 'strawman argument', but your sudden pivot and fixation on them does. The _argument_ I was making is that you are wrong when you say a question must be useful to other/future readers to be asked here. At _best_ we can make a determination about whether something is _likely_ to be useful to future readers, but we can't always _know_.

Comment: Related (from yesterday, also about regex questions): *[What to do when a community is openly hostile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421370/what-to-do-when-a-community-is-openly-hostile#comment933307_421370)*

Comment: The list of examples seem to be for a different question: "What should we do when one person always tries to answer well known duplicates?"

Comment: Also, in at least one case, you both answered and voted to close. You really shouldn't do both; by definition, voting to close means that you think that the question can't (or shouldn't) be answered here (unless you think that you're the only one that should be allowed to answer).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Even if I'd also think these question would not show the "necessary" amount of research effort, I still could not see any reason for *deletion*. Indeed these questions overall show sufficient research effort. Please be aware, that from all my questions that ever have been deleted by users other than the "community bot" there is a certain user showing up in each delete-votelist (besides two other ones that appear quite often). In the regex tag there are many skilled users - Why don't they delete other people's content? Probably for some reason.

Comment: @TylerH "Doesn't this describe... literally all debugging questions?" **Yes, and they should be closed and deleted too.** The close-reason guidance is misleading. If you *actually* take the steps described to create a MRE (emphasis on M), identify exactly what confuses you as the OP and ask a coherent question, it **isn't a debugging question any more**.

Comment: @Tom "but I'm sure there were compelling arguments why too localized questions are perfectly suitable to future visitors and not just more sand." As I recall, the main argument is that we can't know what will actually be useful and what is idiosyncratic to the OP, barring some objective standard like an acknowledged typo (an unacknowledged typo may well be a duplicate of "why does it need to be spelled this way instead of the way that makes sense to me?").

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think that's a matter of semantics. Whether we refer to such questions as 'debugging' questions or something else is a separate matter.

Comment: My point doesn't rely on the name. If the question boils down to "This chunk of code doesn't work; please write the correct code to do what I want", then it isn't an appropriate question **even with** a proper specification of what "working" entails, what went wrong etc. - because the lack of *introspection* (Specifically where is the apparent breakdown? Why is it expected to do something else instead? What are we actually trying to find out about that code? What contextual details are necessary and inherent to the problem?) results in a lack of *applicability* to others.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Questions about non-working code that contain an MRE (the "M" is actually the least important aspect of that acronym by the way) and a clear problem statement (often considered _part_ of  an MRE or MCVE) are typically referred to as debugging questions, and are perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow. It sounded like from your comment above that you don't think they are, and that debugging questions are "something else" (something lesser, that should be closed/deleted). That's what I'm referring to when I say it seems like semantics.

Comment: M is **absolutely** the most important part of the acronym *for the purpose of having useful Stack Overflow questions*. The failure of others to understand this has a lot to do with the site's current problems. By creating a **proper** MRE, the question **is no longer about** the non-working code, but about the behaviour of the example. That is the result of doing the [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) work before asking.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As I recall, Shog et al, who came up with and enforced the requirement on SO, disagreed. I don't really follow your logic about an MRE making a question not about the problem. It _really_ sounds like you're arguing purely semantics now. If I want to foo the bar and I have code to do that and it results in an error that says "error, can't foo the bar. unexpected foo" and I include that and ask "Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it so that I can foo the bar", that's... a debugging question. It's what we here at SO call a debugging question.

Comment: "As I recall, Shog et al, who came up with and enforced the requirement on SO, disagreed." Yes, and they're **very obviously** wrong, and I will keep saying it until they agree with me.

Comment: @Tom I agree with you. There simply is a subset of tags which are allowed because they happen a lot in the domain of programming, whether programmers want it or not. But questions about them are going to always gravitate towards personal support, gathering answers which are code only in nature. And the people who frequent those tags understand that and are lenient. The rest of us... we interfere with their process. Tags such as CSS, SQL, regex, R. They just work differently. As long as they are on SO, there will be misalignment.

Comment: What drives me nuts is when it is closed with the generic reg exp question that does not actually help the user solve their problem. Reg Exp is a PITA for new developers. Linking to a question that has tons of links to docs is not really helpful to people that have no idea what exactly they are looking for.

Comment: @epascarello I mean, it's also kind of bad to just ask for something you have no idea about. As many do. Many questions on regex can be solved with a quick introduction course in the subject which might take an hour. Things like "how to match a number" or "how to repeat a match". I'm talking about the actual `\d` and `*` or `+` things which are part of the most basic of regex knowledge one might have. Yet we get questions revolving around these and other basic concepts all the time. How do you build a useful knowledge base when a significant portion of the entries are on what do letters mean?

Comment: @VLAZ Or people can spend 2 minutes and teaching them in an answer. Some people forget we all were beginners at some point. Yes, some people put in no effort, but there are ones that do and people just close it.

Comment: @epascarello OK, not a knowledge base, then.

Comment: @epascarello just so we're clear - do you endorse answering [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho6FA.png)? Do you believe think it is a unique question that desperately requires a new unique answer? And *while I was writing this comment* it did get [an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIYUv.png).

Comment: This kind of deleting/downvoting has been happening in other SE websites as well. It's not necessarily new or uncommon.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry I wonder if it a part of this is also that people are trying to use up all their available votes in a day. For close votes I can understand that, but for delete votes... Especially if you're babysitting a specific tag that can get to the point it becomes damaging rather than helpful. Or at least sends out a very warped signal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I said earlier that this smelled funny.  Going to be honest with you - this downright reeks.

So let's get some things out the way, shall we?

First, **a delete vote is not a super downvote.**  Deletion should be reserved for those things that are *truly* unsalvageable and are so radioactive that the only way to save the rest of us would be to remove it from the site.

...and yet these questions *were* still deleted despite them having a positive score (which is a wtf).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764588/regex-for-letter-and-number-combination-for-password
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415372/why-this-regex-with-backreferences-work-in-regex101-but-not-in-php

The timeline of this question suggests that it was intentionally voted down to qualify for deletion.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72594776/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Second - the fact that there's the same consistent couple of people who are deleting this suggests to me that there's *some* kind of voting fraud happening here.  If this were a coincidence and they happened to bump into each other every now and again, I wouldn't think anything of it. But almost *every* question here??  Really??  Someone needs to look into this.

Comment: If a small group of users are watching the same tag, their continued involvement with that tag can't be helped, I have a bigger problem with questions marked as a duplicate being deleted. Should a question that was marked as a duplicate have been answered, I have my thoughts on that, and would act accordingly with my vote if the questions had not already been deleted. Manipulating a question so a question can be deleted, give everyone with the delete vote privilege, a bad name. My main community, has a small group of users who submit wet noodle answers, and I vote accordingly on those answers.

Comment: “the fact that there's the same consistent couple of people who are deleting this suggests to me that there's some kind of voting fraud happening here.” I am seriously uncomfortable with this line of reasoning. We’re talking about questions spanning 7 years! You would have no problem finding multiple times the number of „group votes“ for me over that time span - with people I have never talked about voting ever. If that is enough to be seen as suspicious…

Comment: @SecurityHound:  [Don't even get me *started* on deleting duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361373/1079354)

Comment: Some notes: 1. Wiktor shared his reason for deleting questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405495), and they don't seem like use as a "super downvote". As far as I saw, those questions met one of the criteria. 2. It's far from official guidance that deletion is for the worst of the worst. Quoting Shog9 (then CM) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375184), "a closed question should be deleted when there's no chance that it should ever be reopened.". 3. It's quite common there are few users in one tag that actively cast delete votes. I could be accused of the same fraud.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi:  I'm only a mere mortal so I can only interpret what I am shown.  My philosophy here is, there are surely more than two or so people floating around, deleting these questions.  But why do they appear together in this capacity?  That's what needs to be investigated.

Comment: Some people get to complain that they always find the same curators voting to close and leaving feedback on their questions. How is it any different that a specific set of users are active around this tag and curating questions in it roughly the same way?

Comment: @ErikA: I mean, that "no chance that it should ever be reopened" rationale is already out the window at this point, isn't it? A decent number of those questions *were* reopened, so we have to ask in hindsight if deletion really was appropriate.

Comment: @Makoto Were they reopened appropriately, though? For most of these questions, I can see how the delete voters could think they'd never be eligible for reopening, even though they did in fact get reopened.

Comment: @Makoto „But why do they appear together in this capacity? That's what needs to be investigated.” What capacity? People have a couple thousand votes per year. Finding a dozen over more than half a decade can be *anything* from cherry picking over sheer luck to smoking guns.

Comment: @ErikA This is a community plattform. It is expected to act according to the guidelines of the community (Stack Overflow) and not those from some self announced "Tag-Cleankeeper". Over times I have not seen anything improving due to this kind of "moderation". The opposite is the case - there is an unpleasant subtone in the regex tag and as far as I perceived, the regex tag dropped in the ranking considerably during the last years. One tries to sell his obvious shady strategy as a good man's effort but is not.

Comment: It speaks volumes if even high rep users [are scared from asking in the "dragon's lair"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate#comment827145_405460). I also regularly see questions of new users almost instantly getting downvoted and closed. This is unfriendly, hostile and not welcoming at all.

Comment: It also speaks volumes how often people love to remove the objective path and switch to the emotional path instead. I guess it is easier to claim your question was "attacked" and you feel scared and how hostile everything is. Maybe a Stack Overflow fork which doesn't focus on the question but more on the feelings of every user would be in order?

Comment: @Tom I think my observations are very objective indeed :) Emotions are important too of course. They make us aware of what's right and what's wrong, don't they. And they distinguish us yet from machines though we are slowly moving towards each other.

Comment: @Tom:  I would normally agree but every time I've heard people talk about the regex tag, I've heard nothing but horror stories.  I like moderation, but maybe this tag is extra super moderated?  Should we look into it?

Comment: @bobblebubble Feelings are unimportant when it comes to the question if a vote was correct or not. They just derail the discussion and won't help in finding a solution.

Comment: @Makoto You can look into it, but like I said in my first comment (under the question), I don't think there will be solution which actually works and reduces the friction significantly. To fulfill the scope of Stack Overflow it is preferable to have a more general question and the moderation tools are there to work towards that (edit out fluff, require MREs, close as dupes etc.), but Regex questions are very specific in nature due to the specific use-cases and restrictions, so even "typical" moderation, like closing as dupe, can trigger heated discussions. I don't see how this can be solved.

Comment: *and yet these questions were still deleted despite them having a positive score* — how are the two things even related? passers-by may cast upvotes for literally whatever reason. At the *very* least it'd be necessary to check the post history and see if there's **recent** votes, or otherwise votes cast a little while after the question was asked for that to play a role in considering deletion

Comment: I don't think it's fraud or at least not intended as such. People latch on to tags and treat it as their backyard. If that happens to be a lower frequency tag, that backyard bit becomes more true than ever. If said people also have delete votes... it LOOKS ugly from the outside. But it's just people using their site-given freedoms in their own bubble.

Comment: @Makoto: "should we look into it?" Please do. AFAICT, `regex` itself isn't the problem. But a certain user who isn't hard to find on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/topusers might be. He's basically linked to every meta-question complaining about bad behaviors related to the `regex` tag.

Comment: Who has not read this yet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405468/5527985 (also comments). I can't imagine that coordinated voting (especially delete-voting) is within the guidelines here. Voting should always happen by free will and never on agreement. There are reasons that one user has one vote per action and entity.

Comment: @bobblebubble coordinated delete-voting is allowed (like is coordinated close-voting). [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) does it at least. *As long as* the question is effectively harmful (*) and needs to be gone ASAP. (*) These questions are in the grey zone, where they are not *that* harmful to be flagged, but also not useful to be left on the site for any longer. I often see blatantly off-topic questions to be closed very fast and shortly there after be deleted. Not sure if this applies to **every** regex question though...

Answer (score 26):

All "here are the requirements now gimme the regex" questions with no attempt to solve/understand the problem by the OP should get closed as too broad. If they get deleted or not from there is no big deal. This isn't a code-writing service, period.

And the other way around: questions where the OP did make an attempt to solve the problem and that aren't duplicates should *not* get closed or deleted.

As for answers to such questions: if you answer a question that is off-topic, has been asked hundred times before, or is unclear to the point where it actually can't be answered - ***tough luck***, you have wasted your time. And also encouraged more of the same to be posted on the site - now *this* is a big problem.

---

Regarding the specific cases:

- [Regex for letter and number combination for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764588/)

  The OP made some effort to start solving the problem. I don't understand why it was deleted, though it might be a duplicate.
- [Regular expression for accept only 1 occurrence of "space" and "single quote"...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319085/)

  Gimme the regex. Should be closed, not answered. And it was also dupe hammered by a Java gold badger. The OP says "I tried with many expressions" - well so post them, if you need help with correcting them.

  I have no idea why this was re-opened and undeleted. Would the moderator care to explain?
- [Why this regex with backreferences work in regex101 but not in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415372/)

  Dupe hammered. I can't tell if the answers were valuable or if this is a common FAQ answered many times before. I'd defer to the PHP gold badger's expertise in this case.
- [How to remove   whenever it occurs between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338996/)

  This was considered too broad at the time posted. I don't have the expertise to tell if the OP made any effort or if this is "gimme the regex".
- [Notepad++ Regex on xml file - Create new element automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74282311/)

  Dupe hammered by a XML gold badger and two other users. Again, I'd trust the gold badger's expertise.
- [Match a certain word if it is not enclosed in double quotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210752/)

  Gimme the regex. And apparently also a duplicate. Should be closed, not answered.
- [Write a regex to match title case sentence but ignores numbers and special chars...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913442/)

  The OP made some research effort. Curiously, one answerer posted a detailed answer, then later decided to close as unclear. Appears to be a special case.
- [JS RegExp Get Words That Contain String And Dont Have Certain Characters...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563020/)

  The OP made some effort. A Javascript gold badger dupe hammered it.
- [Remove HTML tags and their content from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72594776/)

  Closed as too broad - notably the OP of this meta post both posted an answer and voted to close.

Is there a pattern here? Not really...

Well yeah, some recurring users are stringently casting delete votes on correctly closed questions. This isn't ideal, as these dupes might serve as "goal posts" for search engines etc. But on the other hand it's no big deal either since closed posts are most of the time not considered valuable.

What is unfortunate behavior is that if a new question is good and the duplicate targets are so-so, we should ideally let the question sit for a while in case new, better answers than those in the usual dupe target pops up. Gold badgers are expected to evaluate all posted answers in both posts before closing as duplicate. **The best post should be used as duplicate target, which is not necessarily the oldest.** If none of the answers are valuable and the question has been answered many times before, then just dupehammer away - that's exactly what the hammer is for.

There *is* also a pattern of people answering questions that should have been closed. If one isn't aware/can't find a duplicate but instead answering - that's not a problem. But if the question is a "gimme the regex", then answering instead of close voting *is* a problem.

Personally, I often also downvote answers to obvious duplicates, in case the answer was posted by someone with tons of rep and badges that really should know better. Like when they answered the very same question themselves last week - then it's obvious that they are just farming rep without care about the site's quality and moderation.

Comment: for `Regular expression for accept only 1 occurrence of "space" and "single quote"...`, while the dupe target does include a lot of information about regular expressions, the dupe is "Explain this regexp" while the question is "gime a regex". i don't see how the two are duplicates. Effectively, by that definition we should just shut down asking questions in the regex tag because all of them can be answered by reading documentation linked to from that question.

Comment: @KevinB Oh yeah, I didn't follow the dupe target. Dupe hammering a post pointing at some generic FAQ is almost always questionable. Still, this could/should have been closed as too broad. If someone picked the wrong close reason, that's a minor problem.

Comment: It seems disingenuous to use the phrasing "here are the requirements now gimme the regex" to refer to questions that don't actually use such phrasing. Also, are you confusing debugging question requirements, which include an attempt, with how-to question requirements, which don't?

Comment: to me it looks like gime teh codez, which is just a negative connotation of how to questions, is being blanket considered too broad regardless of the actual question. some of them may actually be too broad, but it's not because they didn't provide an attempt.

Comment: @TylerH I was assuming that the reader would be able to do a bit of abstract thinking, naturally that isn't a quote taken from one of the questions... No, I'm not confusing anything, I thought "This isn't a code-writing service, period" was quite clear.

Comment: it is a code writing service, if one thinks how to questions make it a code writing service.

Comment: Regarding #1, also closed as a duplicate (question with over a million views that nearly exactly answers this question) and reopened by OP. Imho that question shouldn't have been reopened.

Comment: Was just about to say what Erik A said: it is evident from the [first question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57764588/timeline) that a duplicate had been found, but that was taken away while the question was already deleted for no transparent reason.

Comment: Appreciate that you took time investigating each question! I don't have a problem with duplicate status or downvotes, it is about *deletion*. Further I don't think that a question necessarily needs to include code (effort). It can still be/get a great question. Some of the most prominent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/,... just a few from the first page of top ranked regex questions.

Comment: @Lundin I think it's better to say what you mean when answering a question on Meta, instead of hoping that readers interprets your words in the same unlikely way as you were hoping. Regarding "this isn't a code-writing service, period" is, well, wrong at worst, inaccurate due to lacking context at best; most questions that are on-topic here are requests for code. This seems like it's going back to the issue of what to do with 'lack of effort' questions. The current rule is that you downvote them, not close vote them... which also means that they're not off-topic.

Comment: @ErikA Just read through the user's own answers, I think that says it all. It is a strategy and not a good moderation. And further this is a community platform and not a one man show. Trust in the other contributers who are well able to moderate too. And I want to mention not a single other question where I answered has been deleted without this user's name appear on the list (only some few from community bot).

Comment: @bobblebubble What is your point exactly? That Wiktor also answers questions that are duplicates of frequent issues and should've been deleted, so it should be fair game to everyone? I'd argue that if you notice this, you should mark these questions as duplicates and consider deleting them if they do not provide a valuable signpost (e.g. are asking for the exact same thing and likely will be found using the same search, or are unlikely to be found at all due to a poorly formulated problem)

Comment: @ErikA Most who participate in the regex tag know well what's going on. And yes, it's possible to do a "counter moderation". However I'm here for helping others, learning, having fun and spending a good time, not for quarreling and playing disturbing games.

Comment: @bobblebubble This is not about playing games or having fun, at least for me. It's about creating a lasting, valuable repository of knowledge, mainly for the users using search to find answers, and a bit for those asking questions as well. Cleaning up the questions and consolidating answers on one question is essential to that goal imo. It's not "counter moderation", just moderation. If there are duplicates, they should be closed as such, with the most appropriate target. If they provide no value at all, they should be deleted. Simple as that.

Comment: @ErikA I don't get why you are so focused on *duplicates*. I'm complaining about valid (average) questions that have been *deleted* (thrown into the garbage bin). There are [guidelines on Stackoverflow when questions get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions). None of the mentioned questions have imho been *extremely offtopic* or *very low quality*. Such aggressive behaviour of very few but powerful users in the regex tag is disturbing the process of building a "valuable respository of knowlege".

Comment: @bobblebubble And the guidance by a then community moderator shared [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375184) is: "a closed question should be deleted when there's no chance that it should ever be reopened". I get that these reasons are conflicting (hell, on the same post I even argued against deletion), but it is what it is, if these questions are duplicates, and are not of value as a signpost, there is plenty of precedence to say their deletion is valid

Comment: Regarding the "disturbing the process of building a valuable repository of knowledge", that would be a point against deletion, but I don't really see how that's the case. Some users may be disappointed if one of their answers got deleted appropriately, I know I was at some time, but that disappointment should encourage you to help moderate instead of answer questions that should get closed.

Comment: "questions where the OP did make an attempt to solve the problem" I'm going to have to do my own post on this topic, but "attempts to solve the problem" often actively make the question worse.

Comment: Lack of effort on the question-asker side is not a reason for a closure. We close posts that cannot be answered or answering them wouldn't be in the best interest to the community. Closing posts just because you think the person asking the question is lazy is not in line with the goal of this site.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I had this very same debate many times, most recently in comments here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417627/584518. Also note how the answer proposing a return of the close reason "The question must demonstrate a minimum of knowledge/research about the topic being discussed." received _overwhelmingly clear community consensus_ currently sitting at 148 for, 17 against. The community very clearly agrees that this is/should be a valid reason to close questions on SO.

Comment: @Lundin That post contains _three_ close reasons. People might very well upvote or not downvote it because they agree with the first two. The 75 upvotes on Cody's comment show that there clearly is _no_ consensus here. The majority of the posts on Meta discussing this topic end up in favor of not closing these questions. ([Here you can find a bunch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/260828?sort=newest).)

Comment: "There is also a pattern of people answering questions that should have been closed." I no longer believe this is a true issue. A more attuned answer will serve the person who can't find the dupe better than an answer to the dupe.

Comment: @Joshua And since answering is the top priority here while creating a repository of "quality" Q/A is just a unimportant by-product no one needs to bother about maintainability, so we can continue producing the same answer over and over again. Having thousands of outdated answers is easier to maintain then just a few hundred, I agree.

Comment: @Joshua There is a flood of almost identical, often beginner-level FAQ questions constantly hitting the site. The _only_ persons who benefit from not closing them are the lazy kid who asked the question instead of doing basic research, and the rep farming crowd who only answer "low hanging fruit" with an obvious answer. The losers are programming professionals who try to find high quality technical information in the flood of crap, as well as the SO company who get a worse and less relevant product for each and every such post. And the Internet as whole, getting even more trash added to it.

Comment: Just look at any popular tag... In the ones I'm active at, the top 20 users consist roughly of 15 people who are actual technical experts and 5 who are rep farmers of intermediate skill/knowledge. It makes the whole rep system lose credibility.

Comment: @Tom: It would seem my view into stackoverflow is different. Case just brought to my attention because somebody voted on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240861/implement-strcmp-function-in-assembly-64-on-linux/65240970#65240970 I didn't find the dupe either; somebody else did about an hour after I posted answer and I confirmed it was a dupe. The question is otherwise exemplary but it turned out it had been asked before in a different context. I don't think the auto dupe finder was going to find it either.

Answer (score 20):

Here's some tags with this problem that I know of, namely [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml), [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt) and a couple more. The problem in my own words: **these tags have a handful of very prolific and enthusiast answerers who answer about anything that comes across**.

These users are human code generators that aren't interested in helping build a sustainable community. All of those tags are one or two departing users away from becoming a graveyard full of unanswered questions. Those users are barely ever explaining things, they're just sitting with their LinqPad/Regex101/XMLSpy open, pasting any question they see and shaking an answer out within minutes.

Stack Overflow used to have a closevote that said "you don't appear to know what you're doing, go study some more". Ever since that vote option was removed, people have been saying that we don't close questions for lack of effort anymore. Yet the first link in the help center still goes to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users):

> A lot. Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer — if the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking.

You know what those answer-spewing users are doing? They're making earlier answers unfindable, and they're reinforcing the culture that it's okay to ask anything, no effort shown whatsoever. Besides that, we already don't have enough users to vet all answers as they're being posted, the last thing Stack Overflow needs is more unverified, copy-pasteable answers <sup>*</sup>. Often when I point out that a solution is not reusable or misses an edge case, the answer is "but that's not what OP asked". Oh, so you want to change the same pattern a hundred times for a hundred askers? Or do you want to write good code and explain how the user can tweak it?

For those voters, I'd say keep fighting the system and keep down- and closevoting however you like. For the answerers: either support your answer with enough explanation and links so that it can serve as a canonical duplicate answer for future, comparable questions, or go find one to use as a duplicate target instead of typing a new one because one variable name or one letter is different. For the rest of us: go add those tags to your ignore list and pretend they don't exist.

---

<sup>*</sup>: anecdote time: for the last year, I've made a sidestep from my regular dotnetting, and went back to the dark side for a while (PHP). Holy smokes is there a lot of insecure, incorrect code out there in answers, and even those answers get copy-pasted all over the place.

Comment: You're conflating two things here - deleting questions shortly after they're closed and users who answer questions all the time.  They are separate things, although I could argue that one begets the other.

Comment: I agree the question is about the former, Makoto, but its title indicates that the OP here has no idea what the problem is, so I felt compelled to explain one vision thereon. If we didn't have that many questions that serve only one asker, we wouldn't have to close and delete that many. I myself hardly ever vote to delete questions though, so I'm not commenting on that.

Comment: Also too, the very reason that the close reason was removed was [because there were more clear reasons to use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258062/1079354).  Telling someone on a Q&A site that they don't know what they're doing when they ask a question is...kinda obvious, given that they're asking, y'know.  It's like if your uncle asks Google how to carve a turkey, and you give him grief for looking it up in the first place.  It's just...backwards to me.

Comment: The way I have always used and understood that close vote is between "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad", meaning: this question isn't answerable without writing half a blog post, or it doesn't look like you know what you're asking about, so you're not going to understand the answers and you are going to follow up with more questions instead of doing research. The latter was only clear after interacting with the OP, either in comments or through earlier questions. The same screams from many regex questions: "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas".

Comment: Trying nothing *isn't* a close reason.  It's a reason to downvote, sure.  But it's not a close reason.  If you find a duplicate, that's great - that can be attached to the question you've downvoted.  But then it's also not a reason to delete that question, either.  **You are conflating two different things here** although the correlation to causation pipeline is a lot more crystal clear...

Comment: @Makoto I know that's not a reason to close-vote. All I was trying to do with my answer is to give an explanation of why we see such behavior. And I'm saying people should keep fighting the system by using their votes as they see fit, because the askers and answerers don't play by the rules either. I dare say that every regex and every Git question has been asked, people just like typing new answers more than maintaining old, existing ones.

Comment: Homework tags, like [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (now 470,550 questions) and [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) (now 265,239 questions), probably belong in that list. There may even be [payment behind the scenes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632) which drives this, not just reputation points.

Comment: I suspect there are homework generators which make each homework assignment unique, perhaps even for each individual student (to avoid cheating). Thus a whole industry sprung up, with Stack Overflow being part of the loop.

Comment: @Peter I don't visit those tags often enough to confirm whether you're right or not, but I believe you.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  No?  I know for a fact that I asked a particularly unique Git question [back in 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42635091/1079354).  To then suggest that "every question" about either Git or Regex has having been answered just *out-of-hand* is incredibly short-sighted and wrong.  But this does belie the problem.  There is a culture of users who will intentionally find an excuse to close a question because, as you put it, they're not "playing by the rules".  This is not the way this is meant to be done.

Comment: @Makoto of course that was an exaggeration, but every day the same couple of questions get asked and answered over and over again. I think knowledgeable people are wasting their time by repeatedly answering the same questions, and they're making the site worse by adding more answers that will never be reviewed nor found again because of their sheer number. I understand closevoting those is not the way, but dropping the community that built your site and making it easier to post stuff and harder to get rid of it is also not the way to run a site, so again, I understand why it happens.