# Why was this question downvoted so heavily?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I was taking a look at my questions to do improvements due to my question ban. I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593486/extract-blood-pressure-values-from-string) in particular which has a lot of downvotes and I can't understand why. It seems clear, has no duplicates prior to it, and even has multiple answers. Of course, people can downvote for any reason but the number of downvotes on this question wasn't making sense. It seemed absurd.

Are they valid and is the question poor quality?

Comment: The question does appear to be a duplicate though, and was in fact closed as such, until it was reopened. It's possible that some of the downvotes are due to it being a duplicate, though it's generally very hard to explain why content gets up/down votes.

Comment: +3/-5 isn't *so* bad, honestly, in the grand scheme of questions being downvoted.  But if I had to hazard a guess, probably because it's tagged with [tag:regex]?

Comment: @cigien True, it was closed as a duplicate once, but then it was cleared that it was not a duplicate, so it was reopened, those downvotes could be prior to it being reopened.

Comment: @Makoto What's up with the regex tag?

Comment: [I couldn't say, honestly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421392/1079354) @LILLOFIE.  As in, all I have are hyperbole and superstition to go off of. But I've been around long enough to know that my suspicion isn't entirely *wrong*, either...

Comment: @LILLOFIE [Drama](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405460/8967612), [a whole lot of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421392/8967612).

Comment: The question is now reclosed as duplicate, and correctly so. Can anyone with enough reputation kindly check the history of this question and tell me why it was reopened? Because I am curious now...

Comment: You can click on the activity button (the little clock icon just below the saves and voting buttons) and it'll show you the activity on the post, such as which duplicates were used to close the question originally.

Comment: @LILLOFIE Because one of the answerers who has a [javascript] gold badge decided to reopen it. Just as we call out people who incorrectly close and/or unwarrantedly delete questions, we should also condemn the behavior of reopening questions that were rightfully closed.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Very much agreed. Thank you all for taking a look at this.

Comment: @cigien I never realized that was a feature, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I have a hunch that just constructing a proper MRE - one that boils down to „can’t match multiple digits“ instead of „can’t match blood pressure“ - would have been useful to both the asker and others. As it is presented right now - not so much…

Comment: @MisterMiyagi But I needed a very specific one for blood pressure. It had 3 conditions, 1: match multiple digits, 2: Allow a separator in the middle of the numbers, 3: The length of both of those numbers should be a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3. Of course, the most important requirement was to match multiple digits.

Comment: Your three conditions are the very basics of regex patterns. By your logic, every single regex is "specific" because if I want to match *two* digits, that would be one specific question, if I want to match *three* digits, that would be another. Whereas that's all just *exceptionally trivial* variations of "I want n amount of digits". All of them answered by the simple pattern `\d{min,max}` How exactly do you justify that *an infinite amount of questions* all answered by this, are all distinct, and useful to keep in a knowledge repository?

Comment: The basics of regex are matching digits, letters, some specific characters, and quantifiers `+`, `*`, `{min,max}`, `?`. This is not very advanced, any introductory regex course will cover them in an hour or less. I do not see how asking for all and every variation of these basic concepts is useful to keeping around. We generally don't keep infinite amount of questions in the form "how do I make a loop that iterates X times" and then just re-ask it with a different value of X.

Comment: @VLAZ You are missing my point, I **agree** that it is a duplicate of the question, just clarifying the "matching numbers" part to not being the only part of the question. I can safely say that at that point, my knowledge of regex was low enough to consider both of the points equally trivial. Nonetheless, I agree with the points mentioned in the comment above so there was no need to justify that :)

Comment: I cannot even remember why I re-opened. Certainly not because I needed the rep.

Comment: The question just got deleted. Anyone cares to explain why? Are all duplicates deleted at some point?

Comment: @Stranger closed posts matching certain criteria are deleted automatically by [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Although in this case the question was deleted by votes from 3 users.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Okay thanks ,gotcha.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TLDR: The question as written is neither particularly **useful** as a domain-specific nor as a domain-agnostic one. A minimum of **research** should have eliminated at least some of the problems already.

---

To get this out of the way first: Matching *multiple* things and escaping *special* things are very basic regex functionality. Both of these are covered in regex docs and, to stay within Stack Overflow, a simple web search turns up countless Q&A addressing those issues.
Just punching the title into a search engine and restricting it to Stack Overflow leads to the current duplicate target as well as several other Q&A that contain the desired regex pattern.

The real issue, though, is that the question is neither particularly useful as a reference for the domain problem nor the programming problem.

- For anyone with a similar programming problem, the Q&A is practically unfindable. None of the core programming issues – matching *multiple* things and matching *special* things – is spelled out in searchable terms, neither in specific ("match slash") nor generically ("match special character").

  Constructing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the programming problem would help here. Remove the domain specific formulation and it should immediately reveal the above mentioned issues. It is prudent to focus on one issue at a time as well.
- For anyone with a similar domain problem, the Q&A is of questionable value. It is only about your format that is neither clearly specified nor thorough. Is the separator directly adjacent or are spaces allowed? Do numbers have to make sense, as in are `000/0` or `9001/3` valid? Is the format suitable for text extraction, as in what would `should not170/80pass` result in?

  Constructing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the domain problem would help here. Give a clear specification of what the required rules are, ideally referring to some actual standard as well, and provide thorough test cases.

Comment: Well-detailed answer covering the content of the question and what may have resulted in the downvotes. Thanks!

I have another sub-question that I don't think is significant enough to ask a new one which is that currently, I am trying to improve my existing questions to help lift the question ban. Should I really try to improve this question and others that are closed as *duplicates*?

Comment: @LILLOFIE It's a bit hard to speculate on these things, since it effectively means guessing how people will react in an even more complex situation. Personally, I would recommend to edit them even if it's just to get the experience of improving quality. Though if you can try and focus on those questions where the duplicates are of poor quality and make your own one better than the duplicate target, that is a solid strategy for making questions stand out.