# Why delete a closed question waiting for review?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75733955/declaring-an-uninitialised-variable-of-custom-type) which wasn't correct in respect of the minimal reproducible example. It got closed, and two people voted for deletion. Why did they vote for deletion since the question will already be deleted within 48 hours if there is no edit?

I subsequently edited my question to show exactly my problem with a reproducible example, and it got 2 new downvotes, no new comment, and a third delete vote which effectively deleted my question leaving little to no chance for reopening.

Comment: I have no idea why it got deleted. It should not have been deleted. Some users abused their delete privilege here... or simply acted to hastily.

Comment: Does this mean that it was closed for wrong reasons? The comments have been asking for an edit, so what you are saying doesn't make sense. Why would others ask for MCVE if the question cannot be answered anyway?

Comment: "*Why did they vote for deletion since the question will already be deleted within 48 hours if there is no edit?*" Posts are not deletion within 48 hours. There earliest [the Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) will pick them up in is 10 days.

Comment: @Maxence1402 - I hope you will take a hot minute to improve your question. For instance several individuals have pointed out, you failed to provide the compiler error, within the body of your question.

Comment: @SecurityHound I did, unless you consider a comment inside a code block outside of the body of the question.

Comment: @Maxence1402 - No; I don’t consider information within a comment to be improving your question

Comment: You also demonstrated *lack of* demonstrated research effort... The only thing saving that post from -100 rating right now is being linked from meta and semi-official policy is not to downvote post linked from meta... There is stronger guidance to avoid deletion of posts referenced from meta (as those can't be seen by <10K users) - expect trickle of downvotes till this meta post becomes remote past (in a week or so).

Comment: Meanwhile it has 2 delete votes again already... (@Dharman)

Comment: OP has self-deleted the post on main since asking about it here (after it got undeleted by a mod), so I'm voting to close this question as 'no longer reproducible'.

Comment: @TylerH:  No, this is a bit of an endemic in moderation.  This happens far more often than the people care to post *on Meta* about, and we should really start talking about it.  The OP is probably not interested in the headache that some rules lawyers are giving them, but this is precisely why Meta needs to get involved - to start fixing some of this nonsense.

Comment: @Makoto OK, well OP is asking about their specific question, not about the practice in general. Feel free to ask a more general question if you want to discuss it at a broader level. In the meantime OP has clearly chosen a final outcome for their question themselves, so responses are irrelevant.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[This sounds familiar...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421397/1079354)

Some high level things:

- Deletion is not a "super downvote".
- Deletion should be reserved for questions which *are beyond* redemption.

In this case, the OP *very clearly* edited the question to include missing info, to help address the commentator's concerns.

We can't keep doing things like this.  You can't offer a path to redemption that's covered in lava.  No amount of justification from any of the close voters is satisfactory enough to explain why this question was ***so horrible*** that it needed to be ***nuked from ORBIT*** before it had a chance to go through the process.

Comment: But... But... It was the only way to be sure! Sure of what, that I'm still working on...

Comment: @user4581301:  [C'mon Ripley](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Quotes/ItsTheOnlyWayToBeSure), even Corporal Hicks ain't so sure about this one... ;)

Comment: "We can't keep doing things like this." - indeed but... what is to be done? Can the delete privileges be taken away from people?

Comment: @Gimby maybe a gentler approach is to limit the del votes. I currently have 20 del votes a day. I'm not sure if the number differs (e.g., close votes and flags can grow). 20 is plenty most days. Unless I specifically go out to search for things to delete. But if limited to, say, 5 del votes, I assume users would focus casting those on things that really matter, not just recently closed questions which the Roomba will pick up anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ sounds reasonable. That would cut the effective pool of delete votes down by quite a bit though, so to compensate there maybe people should get the privilege sooner. More people with far less votes rather than a few people with lots of votes.

Comment: Looks like I have 27 delete votes. Never even came close to using half of that.