# Good questions that have been deleted

Tags: discussion

I have been watching a very good question (~100 upvotes) with very good answers steadily accumulate delete votes.  It has been up for 9 years, but only in the last month has it accumulated delete votes.

I did a link check and it has 12 external sites linking to it.

I don't really care if it gets deleted but it got me wondering...  How many really good questions (based on upvotes) are being deleted each month?

Is there a way to see deleted questions so I can work to revive the good ones by moving them to an appropriate place?

Comment: No you can't see deleted question, thus you can't look up deleted posts. Someone would need to do that for you, including all the answers there and basic user information about the authors, since we don't want to break copyright laws. I don't think someone will invest their time doing that.

Comment: 10k rep users have access to a list of posts with delete votes, and a list of recently deleted posts. Hope you can earn the privilege in future to help out there. 10k rep also grants you the ability to view deleted posts.

Comment: Indirectly one could see deleted questions by downloading data dumps from different times and comparing the content. That would be a lot of work though.

Comment: Less then 5 on average "good" questions are deleted each month: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1127896#graph

Comment: @rene - awesome graph.  It does seem to have a bug: months with zero deletes are not represented.  For instance Dec 2015.  I found that bug by counting the dots on each year and finding some years have 11 dots.

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to review these popular questions to see who is voting to delete them to make sure the voting system is not being manipulated by people with a financial interest.  For instance, the question I am looking at that is about to be deleted is about an open source alternative to a paid library.  Because the people voting to delete is not available it is no way to tell if the votes are being manipulated.

Comment: That is a bold statement and if this is about the question I think it is then I don't see enough users that have delete privileges by themselves AND commercial interest. So now to make this work they would have to recruit other 10K-ers to do the delete voting. Srsly? Anyway, the info from that Q/A you want to keep can go in the tag wiki. Make sure your edit is of enough quality and substance to get it approved in the review queue.

Comment: Yeah, Seriously.  If I see a pattern: I flurry of delete votes, then it is not far fetched that something is driving the delete activity other than people with 10k rep stumbling on a 9-year-old question.  Thanks for the tip on moving it to the tag wiki.

Comment: Is there a query that will tell me the time that the delete votes were cast on a particular question?

Comment: You don't need a query, just look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4321207/timeline).

Comment: Do strongly upvoted questions really need to be deleted? After all there is still closing available and it's hardly imaginable that these questions are actively harmful.

Comment: Here is a sample of a question that got closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl

Comment: Here is a former moderator's opinion of deleting content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/192044

Comment: "Is there a way to see deleted questions so I can work to revive the good ones by moving them to an appropriate place?" These were already reviewed by at least three 10k+ users. The idea is that these users were trusted enough to make the call. Most often these kind of very posts are old tool recommendation link collections, that are neither on-topic or up to date. Might take someone with domain expertise to make the call. But it isn't meaningful to discuss this without a specific post in mind.

Comment: @MichaelPotter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl is an excellent example of a post that should be deleted _unless_ it is a special case and actively maintained, preferably community wiki etc. I don't see any special reason to keep that post though, this stuff should be in [tag:itext] tag wiki and not in some Q&A that keeps getting outdated.

Comment: At the end of every year Shog also tends to post a list of the top 100 questions or so that were deleted and had high scores/high views so the community can review their deletion. Still requires 10k reputation, though.

Comment: In addition to close and delete they need a "convert to wiki" button.  I don't use this library anymore so its deletion does not affect me, but I will say the content on the question is good.

Comment: Note that the content on Stack Overflow is licensed under [CC-by-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), so you could host the content on your own blog or website if you felt it was so valuable that it needed to be preserved on the open internet. You just need to give [attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).