# Is removing my own answered question not allowed?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977421/jwt-token-passing-in-rest-apis) around a year ago, and now I thought it might not be a useful question on Stack Overflow and I want to remove it. When I click to delete, there is a popup:

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and
>   effort into answering it.

I totally agree with it, but I answered my own question and no other answers were posted by anyone. Why does SO does not allow users to delete questions with only self-answers present?

Comment: It has 200+ views and an upvote on your answer. It might still be useful? You can also dissociate yourself from the post if you don't want it on your account for some reason: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA 4.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you believe your question (and/or the resulting answer) no longer provide value to the community, your best option is to disassociate your name from the post.  You can do this by flagging the post and clicking "other" and then writing your reason for wanting the post disassociated from your name.

The reason that's the best option here is that both your question and answer have upvotes, and that means others have found them useful.  [We don't delete good content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/16587).

Answer (score 7):

1. Unaccept your answer.
2. Delete your answer.
3. Delete your question.
4. Success.

Comment: Wouldn't this get them into more hot water with the q-ban script?

Comment: I suppose then that the 3 people who favorited it are just up a creek, then. :/

Comment: People favorite questions for all kinds of reasons. E.g. I regularly favorite questions to check on closures/deletions.

Comment: I"m just saying. Deleting this question and answer combo doesn't mean that nothing of value would be lost.  *Maybe* something of value *could* be lost.  Yeah, one can force the deletion through, but this at least gives someone the time to really think about what it is they're doing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. It's their post, and they are not circumventing anything. It is simply they way it is designed. They can delete the answer because that's always an option if the answer is not accepted and one is not rage-quitting. They can delete the question because no one else bothered to answer. It's their content, their call.

Comment: Because I can neither confirm or deny that 3 people who favorited this question won't get any value of this question and answer combo, I will happily agree to disagree.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you disagreeing with, but fine. I'm just telling the user they **can** delete their question. The system allows it, they just need to follow a particular set of steps.

Comment: I'm recommending that they *shouldn't*.  Being *able* to do something is not unilateral permission *to* do it.  Your answer gives them the mechanical steps to accomplish this without considering that angle.  *That* is what I am disagreeing with.

Comment: Answer has an upvote - can it still be deleted?

Comment: @AdrianMole you can delete your own upvoted answer. Deleting accepted answer is not allowed.

Comment: @Makoto Q-ban comes into play when deleting *negatively scored* questions. If it's upvoted or 0, there's no harm AFAIK