# How to convince php users to post testable data?

Tags: discussion, tag-tips

A whole load of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions is about [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) manipulations. These questions normally include more or less convoluted examples of inputs and outputs. While other languages' users usually provide raw copy-pastable snippets or jsons, most php folks prefer to post debugger dumps which are not suitable for testing and experimenting with. Recent examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625318/php-new-array-from-multidimensional-grouping-same-key-elements
- [Object in to a array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624064/object-in-to-a-array)
- [Search array by key branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619646/search-array-by-key-branch)
- [PHP - Multidimensional Array Input ( Having File Type & Text Type ) Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616502/php-multidimensional-array-input-having-file-type-text-type-form-submiss)

So when you answer such a question, you either have to post your solution untested or do a tedious job of converting these debugger dumps back to source code.

My questions to people who answer php questions:

- do you have a problem with that, and how do you deal with it?
- do you think it would help if we add a [red popup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/839601) to the ask page saying that it's better to post example data in a testable form?

<sup>(If you're going to make a php joke, I'd love to hear it).</sup>

Comment: You could just close-vote questions lacking testable data with that _"why isn't this code working?"_ close reason under off-topic.

Comment: @Cerbrus: that would be logical, but hardly practical, because the vast majority of questions are this way.

Comment: Did you hear about that [brainfuck compiler written in PHP](https://github.com/igorw/naegleria)?  Why would they put a joke language that people use to troll other developers, and Brainfuck together into the same project?

Comment: Isn't there a canonical question/answer pair that can be used as duplicate target for all those questions as I explained [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251946/duplicate-questions-versus-rtfm/252046#252046)?

Comment: I can assure you this problem is not unique to PHP... :\

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: from my experience, javascripters sometimes posts console logs (or even screenshots. go figure), but magnitudes rarer than php folks. The problem with php is that _most_ questions contain data you can't just copy-paste and play with.

Comment: yeah sometimes when i deal with this, (especially the ones with the heavy nested structure from a `print_r()`) i just politely ask for a `var_export()` if possible, if the OP indeed did make some attempt of solving the problem, if its just straight up dump `print_r()`, i just vote to close

Comment: The problem with PHP is that you get very little feedback from the errors it throws, so people post a lot more "Syntax error" style questions. Perhaps the solution is to demand PHP improve this? :p

Comment: I am struggling with this one as well.  I have seen some attempts at writing a "reverse print_r", but they work 1/5 times.  I have seen some "reverse var_dump" code, it is a bit better, but few OP ask questions with that.  I now ignore many array question just because of that...