# How to suggest that someone's MCVE is not so minimal

Tags: discussion, questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I recently commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026848/submit-form-is-not-working-with-in-bootstrap-model), a typical copy-paste of all their code, asking the user to provide an mcve.

I don't think that the user has made their question minimal, it still requires a database, their inline styles pollute the code, etc.

I was going to suggest they swap their `$row=mysqli_fetch_object($queryrun);` out for an inline array eg: `$row=(object)["key"=>"value", "otherkey"=>1];`, but I can't see any suggestions in [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [php tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) about how to handle database data in a mcve.

For instance, if the database is not causing the issues, I shouldn't have to set up a database to test your code, and the database calls should be removed/replaced with inline data.

**Should there recommendation on the MCVE or (language appropriate) tag with regards to inlining example database data? Or do I just suggest they do this as a separate comment?**

I feel bad, after the user who is both new and has made a small attempt at providing an mcve after bring prompted, going back to them and asking them to clean it up even more.

Comment: Looks like your comment worked. They removed a bunch of code from their question.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins yea but it's still hard to test his code, and because he's already made some changes i feel bad asking him to make more changes

Comment: Why is it hard to test his code? I don't know anything about JavaScript, really, but the code appearing in the question is definitely short enough to be reasonable. There is naturally some give-and-take here on a Q&A site. It's often a lot of work to answer questions, because the asker isn't smart enough to frame them perfectly, but if they were, they wouldn't be having the problem in the first place and they could just answer their own question. That's why answerers are rewarded with more reputation for good answers than askers are rewarded for good questions. Also, you have edit privileges..

Comment: @CodyGray I'm going to close this question, this question is better: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275566/how-to-convince-php-users-to-post-testable-data?rq=1