# Repurposing an existing question into a good canonical question

Tags: discussion, canonical

Every day (pretty much) the [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) tag gets questions about JavaScript only working after a page refresh. The problem is (almost) always the `turbolinks` gem that is included with Rails. I'd like to turn [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317816/rails-javascript-only-works-after-reload) into a good canonical question so the other ones can be closed as duplicates. I chose that one because it has the best, most google-able title.

Is this a good question to use? Should I edit the question to make it a little more universal (i.e. removing most of the JavaScript except for `$(document).ready ->`, which is the problem)? Should I write a new question and answer it myself?

I get tired of these questions, but it is obvious that a lot of people are confused about `turbolinks` so I'd like to be able to direct them to a single question that should help them without polluting the site with a bunch of similar `turbolinks`-related questions.

Comment: It makes more sense to choose a good, general question with a great answer than to choose a question just because of the title. It's much easier to edit the title than the entire body of the question.

Comment: Rather than rewriting the question (suboptimal), you can create a groomed version of it and self-answer.  Flag it and ask for it to be wiki'd so you don't attract derpvotes.

Comment: It is only fitting that this question be closed as a duplicate, and that OP be sent to the canonical question.  Wait, is this stackoverflow meta meta?

Comment: I have written an approach in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/578411)