# How to organize the finding or writing and advertise the existence of canonical questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I know of a few questions that get asked and answered on a daily basis. For example in the C# tag:

- How to read [this JSON] into a model?
- How to read CSV data?
- How to write CSV data?
- Why doesn't my client socket `recv()` what my server socket `send()`s?
- How to parse a DateTime in yet another format?
- How to run a background job in ASP.NET?

Unfortunately, the answers those questions receive often barely scratch the surface of the underlying problem, or they just hand out the solution without explaining how to obtain it, and are bound to let OP return after they copy-paste the provided code - or letting later visitors asking their own, slightly modified version of the same question because the question and its answers are too localized.

I would like to solve that problem by creating (or finding and polishing) a "canonical duplicate", a question that asks about the core problem in the most naive way and an answer that increasingly lets the reader understand the problem and pick any solution they like.

In order to do this, I think such a canonical Q&A needs to go through two phases:

1. Spend some effort into writing (or finding and polishing) the Q&A, but in order to make them not too broad, clear and to the point, I'd like some other users to take a look at them and maybe suggest improvements.
2. Then get other those and users to link to the Q&A as possible duplicates of existing and newer questions.

Now how can I organize all this?

For the first part I could for example create an initial, but (according to the rules) valid "draft" on the main site, and create a Meta post asking for people to look at it?

Comment: Good question.  Should drafts live on the main site or here on meta?  The downside to using the main site as a board for that is all the time before the canonical is complete.  The upside is getting more relevant and immediate feedback from the actual followers of the tags.

Comment: Hmm, there's something seriously wrong if after 860,000 C# questions there still is no canonical Q+A for these common questions.  Surely it is best to not add yet another version.  Keep the best existing ones in your back-pocket, edit them if necessary, ready to go when it is hammer-time.

Comment: I know of one canonical that was created/matured in a chat room. The initial revisions were done off-line, in a gist. You can see if [this answer helps](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251946/duplicate-questions-versus-rtfm/252046#252046)

Comment: @Hans that's part of the problem. There's no single one that I can find that explains the things in a way that they can answer every variation of the same question. Like the date parsing one. There's no question I can find that explains "yyyy" will match the "2015" part from the input at that position, and so on; explaining how one can create their own parsing pattern by mere reading. Then still the second part of my question stands: how to get other people to recognize that one as canonical and use it as a dupe target?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the intent, but isn't this sort of problem what the upcoming [Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) feature will solve? It sounds like we'd have a collection of examples for some of the most common code issues, and we can point people there.

Comment: Perhaps the [documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/4151918) feature could also serve as the reference for dupe target canonical questions, or a repository for broader tutorials that address the common variations.

Comment: @PetahChristian We both posted within 7 seconds of each other... great minds think alike, eh?

Comment: @Nik, Petah, maybe, but it might take 6-8 months until that catches on.

Comment: @rene thanks, quite helpful. So a meta post and visiting chat for the first time seem to be a good start.

Comment: Chatrooms.​​​​​

Comment: Parsing dates is a problem in my home tag, too, that I've been thinking about recently. I don't see how to create a canonical for that one that doesn't just repeat the formatting docs. That seems to be what they all boil down to: "well, your format string doesn't match the input".

Comment: @JoshCaswell: There's a little more to it than that - enough that I felt it worth writing a blog post: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/ It's a common problem in many languages, but often with slightly different nuances in each :(

Comment: The ones I'm thinking of are those that fall under your "Broad Incompatibilities", @JonSkeet. They are near-daily in my language tag, and represent some of the worst of the "I do not care to think about my problem. Give me a copy-paste target" category.

Comment: Maybe you could start an [tag:c#-faq] tag like the [tag:c++-faq] tag and then you can mark the conical's with that tag.  It would make them easier to search/link to.

Comment: I've been noticing a pattern where every time I come to Meta I discover even more examples of people discussing ways to improve the overall quality of the site content, coming up with some good ideas, and then nothing being done. I keep noticing that these questions/discussions appeared primarily in 2014/2015. It becomes more and more depressing as the years roll by.

Comment: Related (shameless self-plug): [What is a beginner-oriented canonical Q&A and how can it help me curate my watched tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was wondering about this as well a while back. How I handled it is that I created a Q/A, explained my purpose in the question (as well as putting the question itself), and then community wiki'd the answer. Once my intent was understood, it appeared to be well-received.

That said, that is a rather informal process, and is prone to the question getting lost after time. **I propose a "nominate for canonical" feature** on StackOverflow. If a question and answer is approved as "canonical", it will...

A) Greatly improve question visibility on "related questions".

B) Community wiki both the question AND answer.

C) Protect the question.

D) Automatically list it on the info tab of the tags it was approved for.

E) Improve its visibility on the "Mark as Duplicate" area.

F) Highlight the question differently in lists, perhaps with a little icon before the question name, to indicate its status.

G) An automatic reputation gain for the OP, since the question is made CW, to encourage the creation of canonical Q&As.

That way, we can actually make canonical questions easier to find, and add a level of authority to their "canonical-ness".

This would also require review and voting for canonical questions, to ensure something only becomes canonical if it *really* shines. Perhaps only users with at least a bronze badge in a given tag can vote on canonical questions.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was hoping for something simpler that doesn't require SE developer interference though.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a more formal method, though hopefully someone will answer and prove me wrong!

Comment: FWIW, I *have* taken to proposing edits to major tag wikis with questions that appear to be considered "canonical". That said, I only added my own after it had been upvoted considerably.

Comment: I wish the defensive CW status weren't necessary, but it seems that it often is. [I firmly believe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204216/159251) that you deserve every drop of rep you get from posting a (good!) canonical pair.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Hmm, interesting theory. I agree, though the wiki features themselves are helpful for canonicals. Perhaps give a significant rep boost to an approved canonical, to make up for the wiki-ing?

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's assuming you write the whole thing yourself.  The reason most are CW-ed is that they really are collaborations of many users, not just one person.  Such situations are exactly what CW is there for.

Comment: Modifying tag wikis seems about the only current way of doing it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [builtin list of the most linked C# questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?filter=all&sort=linked) (the link works if you've opt-in to [participate in testing the new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814)). It is best if it grows organically i.e., any additional organizational effort should try to fix possible issues with the organic growth without replacing the process itself.

The curated list of canonical questions for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) could live in [C# tag's description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) e.g., see FAQs section there (a separate section (e.g., "Frequent candidates") could be created). Being a useful (help find targets for duplicates) list by itself, it may also help promote the candidate questions into the most frequently linked list.

Note: It is not necessary to have an explicit list of canonical questions: everytime you close a question as a duplicate, it creates a link to the original question and therefore such questions are promoted to [frequent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?filter=all&sort=linked) automatically. It avoids the issue that questions in a manually-created list become outdated over time.

It is preferable to use an existing popular question with good answers arisen due to an actual problem instead of creating an artificial canonical question. Anonymous users are redirected to the original question automatically (the chain of duplicates is skipped) and therefore it should reflect the language that people use to ask a question, not the language that an expert would use to formulate a solution (we have answers for that).

Comment: I don't really see how this answers either of my questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster: it answers the question in the title: *"how to organize.."* It side-steps the subquestions by avoiding introducing (if possible) unnecessary high-maintenance artificial manual processes (creating new canonical questions and maintaining corresponding list over time), preferring organic growth instead (found duplicate; close it -- consult the most linked list, google to find a duplicate target).

Comment: The sole premise of my questions is that even if great canonical targets exist, I can't find them and I don't see my peers using them either. So I want to organize the effort: get more people to know about a good duplicate candidate, and together create such targets by editing. Going about it alone isn't going to make a dent.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I understand. If you see a duplicate that has been closed using "bad" target; close the "bad" candidate as a duplicate of a good target and  leave a corresponding comment, to inform people who use "wrong" targets. To help the process, a list of links to good targets  could be  accumulated in a corresponding tag wiki. Eventually, good candidates populate top positions in the automatic most linked list and top links in google are closed as duplicates if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I'll see what I can do with that, and monitor whether it makes a change.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The first link is broken.

Comment: @unutbu: it works if you are logged in (it works for my account, I don't know whether there is a rep. limit).

Comment: Hm. I am logged in, but I get "Page not found".

Comment: @unutbu: perhaps, I'm opt-in to a [new navigation test](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814). What happens if you click [tag:C#] and then select "popular" tab?

Comment: Ah, that must be it. I haven't opted-in and see no "popular" tag.