# Why do some People rarely seem to ask Questions but give a lot of Answers?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I come across a solution that has been answered by a person with more than 216000 points. I won't post any links, because I don't want to single anyone out and also I'd like to respect their right to remain undisturbed.

I am personally impressed by the amount of points, because I believe they correlate with their accumulated knowledge and ability, which is a plateau I aspire to reach.

Yet, while investigating their profiles one things stands out. Their **questions to answers ratio is extremely low**. For example `0,008` resulting from `20` questions and ~`2500` answers.

This ratio indicates either that the person:

1. knows how to search, so that he never needs to ask anyone about how things work.
2. has a separate anonymous account to ask questions and a primary account to answer questions thus separating their lack of knowledge from their knowledge

With new technology constantly emerging and the requirement of users to also evolve their craft accordingly, I believe it is unlikely that a person will never have the need to ask how new things work. So the question is:

**Is it recommended to have a separate account to ask questions, because low-level questions might reflect negatively on your public image?**

Comment: s/knows so much/knows how to search/

Comment: As CodeCaster says, most professional/experienced folks simply know how to search Google and have to ask questions only in truly exceptional situations.

Comment: I've asked a total of 2 questions in my SO life (1 I ended up deleting)... why? Because most of the time I search a LOT before asking and I end up finding my solution myself. When I THINK I need to ask a question, I write up a draft and keep it as a draft for a minimum of 7 days. During that week I will research and edit that draft a LOT. Normally, before the end of the week, all my research leads me to an actual solution

Comment: I swear, i've tried to ask hundreds of questions, but every time I do... I find the solution before I click submit while trying to make my question complete. It can be annoying to think you *finally* have a valid question to ask, just to find the answer and no longer need to ask it.

Comment: If you wonder about the number of downvotes on this post, this bit `Accumulating Points as Career Strategy?` probably has to do with it because it seems to imply that SO "power users" amass reputation to build a career. (You may not have meant to say that but that's what it sounds like.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I *do* occasionally see beginner questions from users who got a lot of rep answering questions in their area of expertise, so I doubt many of these folks have a separate questions account. If anything, many people are under the impression that having a lot of rep gets you some leeway in asking poor or off-topic questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=rep+bias

Comment: I wondered about it. I believe that SO "power users" don't need to "build a career", but I believe that they have a certain "reputation" that they might want to protect. Yet I am OK with the answers right now, but I don't believe they address the question properly. I might reintroduce the question with a different title.

Comment: *I might reintroduce the question with a different title. * - It'd almost certainly be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: *Is it recommended to have a separate account* - No. I'm pretty sure they don't want people using multiple accounts, though I don't know if there's a written rule against it. ETA: Found the Meta SE post: [What's the SO policy about having multiple user accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)

Comment: `but I believe that they have a certain "reputation" that they might want to protect.` I see what you mean but I don't think people like Jon Skeet have a secondary account - nor would their "reputation" be tarnished by displaying ignorance in a certain field. I can say I don't have one, either (apart from a sock puppet for [occasional trolling](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4062178#4062178))

Comment: I take your comment as the satisfying answer I wanted from this thread. I guess you agree to CodeCaster's statement?

Comment: Meta.SE question from 2009: [Do the top answerers have secondary accounts to post questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13530/do-the-top-answerers-have-secondary-accounts-to-post-questions)

Comment: Users with that much rep are invariably experts in the tags they post to.  Nobody is an expert at *everything* but you can't become an expert until you learn how to solve your own problems.

Comment: Following Michael's meta link above, you gotta love the first comment! "More importantly, why do the top askers never answer questions? "

Comment: I have 5 questions and 1218 answers, ratio 0.0041.  . I don't have, nor need any more than one account, nor do I have any search super-powers.  Your conclusions are economical with the facts.

Comment: TBH, I'm considering changing the ratio to zero - my five old, dead questions are now just fodder for malicious downvotes.

Comment: @CodeCaster s/knows so much/knows how to learn/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it recommended to have a separate account to ask questions, because low-level questions might reflect negatively on your public image?

I don't think it is ever recommended to have a separate account, regardless of reason. I *certainly* don't think that people who answer a large number of questions and garner a lot of reputation from those answers are concerned *at all* about the possibility of a question they ask reflecting poorly on them.

If anything, such a person, having had to deal with a great many questions that are poorly formed, incomplete, or just outright incomprehensible, knows first-hand just how important a good question is, and will take the time to compose their questions well. Their questions will reflect positively on them, regardless of what "level" of question they are, because the person will have presented their question in a clear, useful way.

> I believe it is unlikely that a person will never have the need to ask how new things work

Which person?

I agree with your belief in general. But it is certainly an achievable goal that *some* people will never have the need to ask how new things work. It is unfortunate with so much detailed, technical information that we still have so many people who don't seem able or inclined to find it.

IMHO, a big component missing from the educational systems of many cultures (not the least being the US, where I reside) is teaching self-sufficiency and good research skills. Granted, this is harder to teach than rote knowledge, but the benefits are exponentially greater. Research skills in particular have unique needs in today's environment of the Internet; knowing not just what words to type in a search query, but also how to efficiently and quickly sort through the results, and to adapt to the specifics of differing search engines, these are important skills that not everyone has.

For the person who *does* have these skills, they may very well not need to ask another individual how things work.

For what it's worth, one of the biggest reasons I got involved with Stack Overflow is for the learning experience. I know from my own past experience two things:

1. I learn best by teaching others, and find the process enjoyable (most of the time).
2. I am more skilled at using various Internet search engines than many other people.

I also suspect that I am more willing to put in effort to find things, but this is more a subjective measure and not as useful a consideration to bring up.

So, sure…I answer a lot more questions than I ask. Indeed, many of the questions I answer, **I did not know the answer before I saw the question**. Especially early on, when I was spending more active time using Stack Overflow as a learning tool, I very often would search for questions to which I did not know the answer but had a strong suspicion that I would be able to find the answer easily. In doing so, I would learn something new (of course, I targeted my search for questions in the areas where I wanted to learn something new).

Sometimes, this meant the answer was on Stack Overflow and I could just vote to close the question as a duplicate. Other times the answer was somewhere else, or required the integration of multiple sources. In those cases, I would respond with an answer. An answer that the OP *could have* found themselves, if only they'd taken the time, and/or had the research skills.

Your question seems to imply that people who don't ask questions are embarrassed to do so, and either refrain or use a separate account so that they don't have to admit that they are asking questions.

I submit an alternative hypothesis:

**There is a strong correlation between being able to answer questions and being able to find answers independently. The type of person who asks a lot of questions (thus gaining reputation that way) is often the type of person who does not have the skill or inclination to find answers on their own, and so will not wind up answering a lot of questions. Conversely, the person who answers a lot of questions does have that skill or inclination, and so does not *need* to ask a lot of questions.**

It is not surprising at all that high-rep users may not ask a lot of questions. In fact, I suspect that an analysis of user reputation would show very few users whose reputation is sourced in a balanced way from both questions and answers. Some such users surely exist, but on the whole the Internet really does seem to be split down the middle between people who know how to get answers on their own and those who don't.

Comment: I would also argue that there is simply a wide range of knowledge and aptitude among those who write software. The number of years of experience and effort over a career can certainly be an important discriminating factor. But as in so many other disciplines, there are those that truly stand out as experts, and then there is everybody else.

Comment: I believe your alternative hypothesis fits the observed phenomenon best and your answer resonated a lot with me personally. As someone who tries to improve his craft, I believe it is to my personal benefit to make the shift to the second group of people on the internet. Till now it was just too easy to get a quick solution to a current problem by asking. I guess the easy way might not always be the best way.

Comment: _"the easy way might not always be the best way"_ -- indeed, in life there are plenty of examples of when one should not take "the easy way". In the short-run, an individual might serve themselves best taking the easy way, but in the long-run we are better off as a community when individuals put in more individual effort, in a way that _reduces_ the overall effort of the community. This benefits even the individual that could otherwise have put in less effort.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Wanted to say that I indeed adapted my style of researching thanks to your insights. Thanks you for this.

Answer (score 23):

Your conclusion is invalid.

People who don't ask many, or any, questions, don't "know everything" nor "have an alt account to ask questions".

Did you consider that those users simply know how Google works and how to piece the information from various sources together?

Comment: Well. I updated the post to reflect this. The question still stands. I believe a lot of people know how google works. Maybe the difference lies there, that some people rush to ask and others elaborate and research more. Possibly.

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness The reason why I've only posted 2 questions on Stack Overflow despite posting 408 answers, including 2 posts that answer the 2 questions I asked, is because I'm able to find the answer to my questions without asking here. I don't use a separate account to ask questions and there's no reason to assume anyone else does.

Comment: RE: *"how to piece the information from* ***various sources*** *together"* By "various sources," I hope that first and foremost you are referring to StackOverflow!

Comment: @DavidRR not really, unfortunately. In my opinion SO's quality is declining, and it is becoming harder to find an actual good answer to certain questions that do not simply state _"Here OP, I fixed your code"_. But nevermind that, that's not a can of worms I'd like to open in the comment section here. It _is_ true that in general, one can answer their own question by doing a web search constrained to the stackoverflow.com domain. You just have to know what to search for and which Q&As to ignore.

Comment: @CodeCaster Earlier today, I saw the sentiment you express here in your recent question [How to organize the finding or writing and advertise the existence of canonical questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308371/1497596). StackOverflow is certainly a work in progress and one that will never end. The goal of we its users is to improve its content and usefulness over time. I myself have profited greatly from the content on SO. While I agree that at times it takes effort to sift through SO to get what I need, the votes and favorites I leave behind bring me back with less effort.

Answer (score 8):

I probably have a similar profile than the one you describe, I can give you an answer from my own point of view.

I genuinely enjoy answering programming questions, I find it keeps the skills I already have up to date, and helps me to learn some others.

Unfortunately (or fortunately), I rarely am in a position where I am unable to work out how to do something with programming - that comes after many years of doing it professionally. I have to say, when I have got stuck, StackOverflow users have paid me back in droves.

Comment: RE: *"StackOverflow users have paid me back in droves."* Indeed, that statement represents the very reason for the existence of StackOverflow: to be a comprehensive knowledge base for programmers. If a well-regarded programming question isn't on SO, it should be!

Answer (score 4):

Being able to effectively ask a question can be seen as a **good** thing. I doubt there are many high rep users who use a second account just for asking questions. If you're able to answer so many questions, surely you'll be able to ask a question that will instead net you a gain in reputation rather than a loss.

I certainly wouldn't look down at a possible new employee just because they have an SO account with a lot of questions, instead I would look at those questions and see if they were well formed and well researched. (the last thing i want is an employee that's going to come to my desk every 5 minutes..) I would however monitor a user who has a lot of answers to see how much time is spent answering questions here vs doing their job.

> Is it recommended to have a separate account to ask questions, because low-level questions might reflect negatively on your public image?

I would not recommend having a second account to ask questions. It is inconvenient, and low level questions on your account *should not* reflect negatively on your public image. Instead, they may show a progression of knowledge from when you first started with said language to when you began answering questions for it.

Comment: Oh dear, my future employers are going to *slay* me!