# Is there a list of common "FAQ" type questions with their best existing versions somewhere?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

I have this problem often: a new user will come and ask a question that is asked repeatedly on Stack Overflow, but when I try to search for a duplicate, I find tons of slightly different things, none of which seems quite good enough to answer OP's question. Typically, the underlying problem will be the same but the code is quite different (because a different task is being undertaken), and the answers are specific in a way that I expect will make them not as easily understandable by/applicable to OP's case as I'd like. Alternately, sometimes there are just a whole bunch that are all at low scores with low-scoring answers and it's hard to say which is best. Sometimes those questions will in turn be closed as duplicates, which at least gives me a trail to follow; but usually they are not.

Some questions don't have this problem at all (the go-to is very clear); others are tricky, and there's seemingly no rhyme or reason to it. Specifically, I'm asking at the moment because I tried to help someone with a basic "what does `UnboundLocalError` mean in Python?" question and ran into a wall of near-misses. It's frustrating because I already know from experience that "what does `NullReferenceException` mean in C#?" is much more easily closed as a duplicate, and the question is comparable in basic-ness.

Comment: Sometimes this list is maintained by the community in the corresponding tag wiki. Otherwise, I don't think there is such a list. When the site search fails, I generally turn to Google.

Comment: There is also the "Frequent" list filter. I just quickly scanned that list in python tag and came up with several possibles that also link to other duplicates. However same solutions were simpler to find in google as mentioned

Comment: Related: [How to organize the finding or writing and advertise the existence of canonical questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308371/how-to-organize-the-finding-or-writing-and-advertise-the-existence-of-canonical)