# Canonical answer to "how does this regexp work"

Tags: discussion, canonical

People have discussed how to deal with "write this regexp for me" questions, but I'm wondering how to deal with "tell me how this regexp works" questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554277/explain-how-does-this-regex-work).

I can leave a comment suggesting they use one of the online regexp testers which provide a sort of pseudo-English reading of the regexp, but actually I'd prefer a canonical answer that I could provide or close as a dup against.

Comment: Ìf you want to create a canonical you can use [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/578411) but the process described there let to the creation of the q/a pair Paul linked to ...