# How to ask for a canonical answer to "How to fix 1064 error?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, canonical

In this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731837/how-to-fix-1064-error I'm hoping to get a canonical, generalizable, answer to a problem that seems to vex a lot of beginners in an area where I contribute.

It's a simple question. I'm intending to use a whole bunch of rep points on a bounty for it when I can, in hopes of getting a wonderful, clear, answer, that we can use to help beginners without reinventing the flat tire for each detail question on the topic.

I can't find an existing canonical answer to this.

My meta-questions:  Is it OK to try to do this? Is this a reasonable use of SO? Am I going about it right?

All feedback is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: How does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21066239/1288) look for a canonical link target? (I mean aside from the "use PostgreSQL" suggestion at the end.)

Comment: I've written an answer trying to describe the process to get to a canonical Q/A pair [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/578411)