# Procedure and requirements for writing a canonical question/answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

I noticed over the last few days that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685751/unable-to-correctly-write-ternary-operator-in-javascript) [particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665350/confusion-with-hasownproperty/37665439) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027021/understanding-ternary-operators-with-concatenated-strings?rq=1) [keeps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028574/ternary-operation-js-not-working?rq=1) [showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444009/concatenate-string-with-ternary-operator-in-javascript?rq=1) up. I went searching for a good canonical question to deal with all of these and wasn't satisfied with what I found.

[I wrote up my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689353/ternary-operator-not-working-during-concatenation) to hopefully serve as the solution to this. But it was quickly downvoted and marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847853/using-the-ternary-operator-with-string-concatenation), which I had come across. I chose to go ahead and write this other question because I thought the answers to the duplicate, while correct, were lacking in information and the question could be generalized a bit to cover other cases of the same bug.

So here's what I'm wondering: under what circumstances should we write a canonical question and what could/should I do to improve the one I wrote?

Comment: This gets you started: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/578411

Comment: Thanks @rene. I didn't see that when I went searching.

Comment: The question where I wrote that is not an duplicate of yours so I won't blame you ;)

Comment: see also: [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions)

Comment: also related: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)