# How can I add a canonical Q&A for a question that keeps showing up in similar forms?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I have been seeing a *lot* of questions come through in the Android tag recently that are all basically minor variants on the same core question.

These questions usually get answered with basically the same short list of solutions every time too, usually specifically tailored for that particular question so it makes marking duplicates more ambiguous and I haven't been able to find a good canonical question/answer to mark them as duplicates of.

What is the right procedure for adding a canonical/reference question to this effect to collect the good answers and start flagging some of these as duplicates?

Is it bad form to just ask the canonical question and start collecting answers (or downvotes...)? Should I indicate in the question that it's intended to be a reference, rather than asking about a specific problem I'm having (e.g. to explain why it doesn't have specific code samples)?

I read through the answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325788/procedure-and-requirements-for-writing-a-canonical-question-answer), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251946/duplicate-questions-versus-rtfm) (among others) and came away with advice ranging from "just do it" (post the Q & A) to a nine-step process starting with "Improve the tag wiki" (presumably need to post the question before being able to list it in the FAQ) and involving lobbying the developer community and contacting moderators.

Those questions are several years old now and didn't really give me a clear idea of how to best go about this. Is there any updated advice?

Comment: if it is a frequently asked and answered question, why is a new canonical q&a needed?  Can't one of the existing answered questions be the canonical

Comment: Is there a SO chat room where you can coordinate a bit? The Python chat room uses a [canonical list on a supporting site](https://sopython.com/canon/), and occasionally writes new canonical questions (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for an example). Basically the [process that Ffsegydd describes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276016/100297), a process driven by a community that cares.

Comment: @psubsee2003 baggage is the usual reason for wanting to write a canonical, as a question with baggage can be closed as a duplicate of a question without, but closing such a question as a duplicate of a question _with_ baggage is... less than ideal.

Comment: @TinyGiant Exactly. A lot of the questions are very specific (I have these two Activities, trying to do X and it's not working right, etc...) so while the answer may be generic, the questions are often pretty different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is an Android chat room, I'll ping folks there to see opinions too. I haven't seen much there in the way of discussion about this sort of thing before though.

Comment: That said, the references here don't really disagree all that much. The important takeaway is that the question must be a really good question on its own because it is going to get a lot more attention than any normal variant would. It is going to seem inherently shady to regulars who don't know what is going on, which is why it is important to be clear about what you're doing. Whether that means a comment on the question, or starting a chat room and inviting discussion on the topic, or whatever the extreme here is, is determined by _what you feel is necessary for the task at hand_.

Comment: What's the core question you want to do this for?

Comment: @MikeM Questions about persistence and accessibility of data in different components (e.g. I stored some data in MainActivity, how can I access it in another Activity to view or modify it? why did it go away when I re-launched the Activity? How do I call methods from one Activity in a different one? etc...). Upon more searching, I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) so this whole question may be irrelevant, at least with regards to sharing data...

Comment: @MartijnPieters we have quite an active android chat room but most regulars 1) do not have moderation privileges 2) lack android "expertise" (probably about half of us are not even android developers) 3) are not interested in moderating content. The latter is mostly due to the sheer amount of garbage that the android tag produces

Comment: Aside from baggage, one possible reason not to use existing questions for a canonical is that there simply isn't a clear choice. Sometimes the question is frequently asked and answered, but it's *always* asked *very poorly* and a lot of the answers are also poor. Sometimes there are three distinct, good ways to answer the question, and the representative answers are on different questions. And sometimes you just tear your hair out trying to do the search.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 4 years later there is still a steady stream of these questions (along with the newer "I don't know how asynchronous programming works" questions...). The vast majority of the time closing as a dupe results in "that doesn't answer my question", with not even enough time to have read the question and answers before commenting, or maybe only reading the first answer... This is one reason I think there should be some sort of rep gain for closing as a duplicate instead of just answering again.

Answer (score 19):

I don't claim to represent anyone but myself, but I've done this close to a dozen times now, and my philosophy is to reuse existing Q&A as much as possible:

1. Make sure you're very familiar with not just the topic, but with the kinds of questions that get asked on SO, and that you've proven you can write answers voted high quality by users of the tag.

   A gold tag badge + insta-edit privilege tier might be a good rule of thumb, and additionally helps make the process easier.
2. Make an exceptional effort in your search for a duplicate.

   It probably doesn't need saying, but check both SO search, Google and tag wikis of the relevant and related tags, including possible different wordings.
3. If possible, improve an existing question--answer pair for canonicity.

   Obviously don't hijack or misrepresent anything, but suggesting positive edits that make a good question/answer even more helpful to more people is definitely a good thing.
4. If there's no salvageable answer, improve a currently active question.

   Any such edit must again be an undeniable improvement to the existing question, and not change its intent or meaning. This is helpful in itself, and allows you to be even more helpful by posting your own high quality answer.
5. If all else fails, post a high quality, self-answered question using all the best practices.

   If it reuses/collects a lot of information from previous answers, post it as a community answer.

Finally make it discoverable by adding it to a tag wiki or similar, using good SEO, and close the currently unanswered questions. The questions that already have good but tailored answers don't need to be closed.

---

> Is it bad form to just ask the canonical question and start collecting answers

Yes, it's bad form to post a question you know is a duplicate. Don't ask people to take time answering a question you don't even need the answer to.

Either self-answer it, or if you really want to source canonical answers from others, put a "Canonical answer required" bounty on it.

> it doesn't have specific code samples

If your question doesn't have a MCVE, then it's probably not as good as it could be.

> Should I indicate in the question that it's intended to be a reference

No. If the question is intended to be a useful and general reference, it should be obvious from the quality of the question itself, and the fact that it's self-answered or has a canonical answer bounty on it.

Comment: "post a high quality, self-answered question using all the best practices": unfortunately, the posters of the previous, "not quite" canonical answers can then feeal that you are "stealing" what ought to be "their" duplicate.

Comment: @Raedwald then make it a wiki? Doesn't stop them from feeling bad about it but it can help show good intentions. May as well link to the meta post discussing the creation of a canonical QA too.

Comment: @Raedwald Definitely. This is why it's the last resort, after first trying to improve an existing Q&A.

Comment: I strongly recommend you work with several other high-score users in the tag(s) to ensure that you have both a well-vetted text and a group of people committed to closing other questions as dupes of it to help get it more well-known to the community. Working together also guarantees you'll have at least one or two people will full edit privileges and potentially even Mjolnir privileges.

Comment: I also disagree on your last point, many good canonicals explicitly state that they are canonicals. Remember that you can't see on the question page why a bounty was offered once it is complete, you can only see that a bounty was awarded. You'd have to go into the post history page to see the reason for it.

Comment: @TylerH Do you find that this helps future readers, e.g. by being able to add `canonical` as a search term? I've mostly done this for the `bash` tag where there's a central FAQ list on the tag wiki, so no searches are necessary. I'm assuming you don't care to know whether a question was intended to be canonical, unintentionally became canonical, or was improved later.

Comment: @thatotherguy I don't personally do it because I don't write many canonicals, but I feel it helps inform future readers of the scope/importance of what they are reading and also helps prevent potential editors from making trivial editors or attempting moderation acts on it like closing it as a dupe of an older question, until it gets a special closure or lock reason, which some older canonicals get (like the C# book list, IIRC). I admit, the canonical callout is much more common in Meta than on main, but I am pretty sure I have seen it several times.

Comment: @TylerH Those don't really seem like bad things to me. SO blocks trivial edits by low rep users already, and if a high rep user wants to fix a typo, I would encourage them to do so on canonical questions as much as (if not more so) than lower traffic questions. Similarly, if someone is able to find a good previous duplicate that I didn't, I would encourage them to dedupe so we can all use that question instead.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm not talking about beneficial edits. I mean things that would otherwise not be blocked by the system but typically should be rejected anyway. A disclaimer that this is Some Important Post(TM) may tend to scare away some of the people just looking to make pointless stylistic (or wrong) edits, akin to extra lighting deterring some would-be thieves/burglars. And no, the point of the canonical is to provide a broad, generic implementation of the question that can be answered with the most exhaustive list of methods. Remember that canonicals are about the answers, not questions.

Comment: @thatotherguy Even when not thinking about canonicals, you still should close questions of others based on which one has the better answers and is the more broad; it is better to close an older, higher upvoted question as a dupe of a newer/less voted one if the newer/less voted one has better/more broad answers that can be tuned to different applications, for example. As canonicals go, there'd be no point if it would simply be closed as a duplicate of another target question. You should then make *that target question* the canonical if closing as a dupe of it is the right move.

Comment: @TylerH If you find that some tags attract significant pointless/wrong edits, then I absolutely support putting a disclaimer or lock on it. I suggested not adding a disclaimer because 99%+ of linux/bash edits I receive are positive in smaller or greater ways, so I obviously prefer that over receiving fewer helpful edits, or potentially training newbies to think that tagging as Very Important Post is a good way to promote a question. It's a purely pragmatic balance, not a philosophical stance.

Comment: "improve a currently active question" - this seems typically impossible, because the questions that most desperately need canonicals are ones that arise out of a *pattern* in what people with low-quality debugging requests are getting wrong, but every such question carries tons of context that can't be properly trimmed away without changing the meaning (to OP).

Comment: "If your question doesn't have a MCVE, then it's probably not as good as it could be." Many of the site's most important canonical targets lack code entirely, because they are basic reference "how do I do X?" questions where X can be understood without any context.