# Closed as duplicate on a question close as to broad (self proclamed canonical)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical, abuse

I recently end up on this question "[How to use java.util.Scanner to correctly read user input from System.in and act on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26446599/4391450)"
That is a closed question ("too broad") based on a moderator a while ago. But I noticed that this self proclamed canonical Q&A was used 100+ times to closed other question since it was closed.

You can find the following note :

> This is meant to be a **canonical question/answer** that can be used as a duplicate target. These requirements are based on the most common questions posted every day and may be added to as needed. They all require the same basic code structure to get to each of the scenarios and they are generally dependant on one another.

A comment was posted on the answer mentioning the problem that I noticed :

> I think the signal to noise ratio in this answer is way too low. It's supposed to be about Scanner, but there's things like immutability, sets vs switch, and a lot of other things. When you go around marking questions that can be answered in 3 lines of code as a duplicate of this you do nothing more but confuse them. [...]
>   *[corsiKa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330057/corsika) Aug 15 '17 at 17:12*

**Questions**

- Why is it permitted to use a closed question (especially one being too broad) ?
- Is it an abuse from the person using that bad question (using his gloden java badge) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Duplicate questions" versus "RTFM"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251946/duplicate-questions-versus-rtfm)

Comment: I noticed I was going everywhere in this question, I have edited it to focus on the main problem (that I was hiding to keep it polite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct form for a canonical Q&A ?

A good canonical question is just *a good question*.  That's it.  *All* questions on SO are expected to be the canonical version of that question.  The duplicate target you have linked is not a good question, because it's *way* too broad *hence why it's closed for that reason*.  A good question would be much more specific, and wouldn't be asking lots of separate questions.

As for the question that was closed as a duplicate, as you mentioned, it's...quite a poor question.  It doesn't contain a very good description of the problem, it doesn't have a MCVE, it's poorly explained, and it's a poorly researched question.  Personally I'd prefer it to be closed for one of those reasons, rather than as a duplicate, but I don't care enough to want to try to reopen the question just to have it get closed again.  That's a lot of work for basically no gain.

Someone has since added a second duplicate target of a better question (that duplicate target isn't too broad, it's still just regurgitating the documentation of the method), making it even less appropriate to want to reopen the question.

> Why is it permitted to use a closed question (especially one being too broad)?

If the same question is asked twice, why is it a problem for one to be closed as too broad and another to be closed as a duplicate of the other?  Lots of close-worthy questions are asked repeatedly.  Yes you *could* argue for closing all of the questions for the non-duplicate reasons that apply, but I don't see a reason to *prohibit* closing questions as a duplicate of a closed question, because there are plenty of cases where it's merited, even if this one case isn't a stellar example of it.

> Is it an abuse from the person using that bad question (using his gloden java badge)?

Honestly I'd say yes, but not just because of this one question (just one question you could argue is merely a disagreement over whether or not it's a duplicate), but it's pretty clear that the user is trying to close basically every question they see asking about an entire broad topic as a duplicate of this one question, and that's just not appropriate.  Looking through the history of all of the questions they've closed as a duplicate of that question makes this not just a theoretical concern as well.  The question is way too broad, and closing questions as a duplicate where 95% of the content of the duplicate is entirely irrelevant because there's some information buried somewhere in the whole thing that's relevant just isn't appropriate.

Comment: What could be the solution to prevent this kind of abuse ? Seems a complicated to "reopen" a question where one only need his own decision to close it.