# Dup target for C and C++ "why does this incorrect program work" questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I fairly often see questions about C or C++ programs involving a question or claim along the lines of:

- "I expected this program to crash, but it didn't. Why not?"
- "I heard doing this is undefined behavior, but it works just fine for me. How can it be working?"

It would be nice to have a standard question covering these sorts of questions, with at least one good answer explaining what "undefined behavior" does and doesn't mean in C and C++.  That question could be used as a duplicate when incorrect expectations about undefined behavior are the main point of the question, or as a link for additional information if something else in the OP questioned or implied confusion about the topic.  I would think this question would be an appropriate duplicate whenever the questioner clearly understands that there's something "incorrect" about the example program or function, whether or not they use the technical phrase "undefined behavior".  But usually if the questioner is expecting some incorrect code to work or is asking about its correctness, an explanation about why that particular code is incorrect would be more helpful.

The existing question [Undefined, unspecified, and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) is close, and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/459640) does briefly mention and explain some confusions about undefined behavior "crashing" or "working", but someone who reads just the title and question might not see an obvious connection to a question about some specific incorrect code.

I know sometimes questions are created with self-answers just for purposes like this, and maybe the "community wiki" mode would be involved.  Would that be a good idea for this case?  If so, how should the question part be written to be general enough to obviously relate to various duplicates but still have the form of an actual acceptable question?

Comment: Yeah.. I often close those as 'Unclear'.  If some app has known bad code, it's unclear why the OP doesn't just fix the bad instead of asking why 'seems to work OK' is not in the set of undefined/unspecified/implementation.   I don't see such questions as useful to future users/visitors:(

Comment: That standard was already set, many, many years ago.  Newbies can't possibly understand the relevance of "nasal demons".  Not so sure it made all that much sense 26 years ago either, I wasn't aware of special nose problems back then.  But this stuff invariably has to be wrapped into magic incantations to hide the fact that the experts don't know the answer either.  Not the SO way.  All the cargo cult-ers have to do is listen to *somebody* that does, no comments necessary.

Comment: If you decide to create a Q&A pair, consider reading some questions about the term [meta-tag:canonical]. [Here's an answer by rene which lists some steps toward creating such a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/215552).